# Will it halt? (Cops)

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, cops-and-robbers

*This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135365/58826).*

Your challenge is to make a program that runs forever without halting<sup>1</sup>, unless it gets a particular input or inputs<sup>2</sup>. If it receives that input, it must terminate in a finite amount of time<sup>3</sup>. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer that has not been cracked by a robber within one week of posting wins. After the week has passed, please mark your answer as safe and show the halting input (in a `> ! spoiler quote`). If a robber cracks your submission, please mark it as cracked and show the halting input (in a `> ! spoiler quote`).

Submissions are preferred be runnable & crackable on [TIO](https://tio.run). Submissions not runnable or crackable on TIO are allowed, but please include instructions to download / run them.

Please make your input deterministic, and uniform across all runs. See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13421/58826) for details.

**Please, don't "implement RSA" or anything mean to the robbers. Use obscure languages and features, not boring encryption and hashing. I can't enforce this with rules, but you can expect torrential downvotes if all you do is `sha(input) === "abcd1234"`.**

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Assuming that the computer doesn't get shut down, break, get engulfed by the sun, overheat in the universe's heat death, or hit the TIO timeout of 60s.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>The program must halt on **at least** one input. As long as it loops forever on one input and halts on another, it works.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup>This must be < 60 seconds, so that the code can be tested on TIO.</sup>

---

## Looking for uncracked submissions?

```js
fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/135363/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36vlFcdkRGfButLhYEngU&key=kAc8QIHB*IqJDUFcjEF1KA((&pagesize=100").then(x=>x.json()).then(data=>{var res = data.items.filter(i=>!i.body_markdown.toLowerCase().includes("cracked")).map(x=>{const matched = /^ ?##? ?(?:(?:(?:\[|<a href ?= ?".*?">)([^\]]+)(?:\]|<\/a>)(?:[\(\[][a-z0-9/:\.]+[\]\)])?)|([^, ]+)).*[^\d](\d+) ?\[?(?:(?:byte|block|codel)s?)(?:\](?:\(.+\))?)? ?(?:\(?(?!no[nt][ -]competing)\)?)?/gim.exec(x.body_markdown);if(!matched){return;}return {link: x.link, lang: matched[1] || matched[2], owner: x.owner}}).filter(Boolean).forEach(ans=>{var tr = document.createElement("tr");var add = (lang, link)=>{var td = document.createElement("td");var a = document.createElement("a");a.innerHTML = lang;a.href = link;td.appendChild(a);tr.appendChild(td);};add(ans.lang, ans.link);add(ans.owner.display_name, ans.owner.link);document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(tr);});});
```

```html
<html><body><h1>Uncracked Submissions</h1><table><thead><tr><th>Language</th><th>Author</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: What counts as "forever"? For example, if the program builds a growing array, can we assume infinite memory?

Comment: @LuisMendo assuming infinite memory is fine

Comment: @programmer5000 Thanks for clarifying. You should incorporate all this into the challenge text. Answerers are not expected to read all comments

Comment: Can we restrict the input to, say, an integer? A robber could pass in some malformed or mistyped input to terminate the program immediately. I'd either have to do lots of careful input validation, or use a language that can catch arbitrary errors.

Comment: @xnor I think you're supposed to have to do the input checking.

Comment: @StepHen That works if the malformed input is still able to be parsed by the interpreter. If I enter an illegal string, `R` errors immediately, without even entering the function to crack. I would argue that that doesn't count as actually terminating the function.

Comment: [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC/wiki/ArnoldC#statements) is also out essentially automatically, as any input other than an integer is unsupported by the language and will throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: Is using random functions off the table then?

Comment: @StackMeter If you have some use for randomness that doesn't render the behavior of your overall program non-deterministic, then go ahead (probably), but unless you're using an esolang where it can't be avoided like Lost I'm certainly having a hard time thinking of why.

Answer (score 57):

## Malbolge, 128 bytes, [cracked by KBRON111](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136004/3808)

```
(=&r:#o=~l4jz7g5vttbrpp^nllZjhhVfddRb`O;:('JYX#VV~jS{Ql>jMKK9IGcFaD_X]\[ZYXWVsN6L4J\[kYEhVBeScba%_M]]~IYG3Eyx5432+rpp-n+l)j'h%B0
```

Have fun!

(Yes, I learned Malbolge just for this. Yes, it took an absurdly long time to finally get working. And yes, it was totally worth it.)

Wrapped, so you can see it in its full, er, "glory":

```
(=&r:#o=~l4jz7g5vttbrpp^nllZjhhV
fddRb`O;:('JYX#VV~jS{Ql>jMKK9IGc
FaD_X]\[ZYXWVsN6L4J\[kYEhVBeScba
%_M]]~IYG3Eyx5432+rpp-n+l)j'h%B0
```

I used [this interpreter](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge_interp.html) to test it; I'm not sure if it matters, but I figured I'd specify just in case.

Comment: That's the interpreter TIO uses btw.

Comment: oh, "Have fun" is good addition

Comment: You're a jerk. Malbolge is mean.

Comment: I'm stamped... The farthest I got: out of 13 inputs before halt, only first and third have any impact. After thorough reverse-engineering, I found that first input has to be `6` and the third is one of the four: `!`, `#`, `/` and `-`. But the combination doesn't seem to fix the halt. I put it out here, maybe someone smarter finds a solution. If anyone wants, I will post tomorrow how I got to these inputs. EDIT: Now that I think about it, my program I wrote for purpose of reverse-engineering this might have a bug, and the first input may be something else than `6`. Third character still stands.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136004/21194) by [KBRON111](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72703/kbron111).

Answer (score 24):

## JavaScript (ES6), 17 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135375/58826)

```javascript
x=>{for(;x==x;);}
```

On TIO, since I dunno how to do Node.js readline on TIO, just stick the input in the function call. This is obvious to anyone who knows it, and not to anyone who doesn't.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q46Lb9Iw7rC1rbCWtO69n@ahuZ/AA)

Answer:

> The answer is `NaN`, since in JavaScript, `NaN != NaN`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135375/58826). Nice usage of a language oddity!

Comment: You bet :) I like how you were so confident that's what I picked that you edited it in for me :P

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is false in many languages other than JavaScript. I wouldn't call it a "language oddity".

Comment: In fact, this very problem of making `while(x!=x)` an infinite loop is [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/contents.html) #29 "Bride of the Looper"

Comment: i believe `NaN != NaN` is a feature of floating point numbers

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: That's correct.  The relation between two IEEE floating point numbers can be above, equal, below, or **unordered**.  The comparison result is unordered if either or both operands are any kind of NaN.  (IEEE 754 binary floating point has many [NaN bit patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding): anything with the exponent all-ones and a non-zero mantissa is a NaN, regardless of the sign bit.  There are some rules for which what goes into the "payload" of a NaN, and for propagating that through operations like `+` or `max()`, but most people don't care :P)

Comment: Fun fact: `-0.0 == +0.0` according to [IEEE754 rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  This is the only case where two values with different bit-patterns compare equal to each other.  All other cases are either unordered or above/below.  See also this excellent series of articles on floating point, by Bruce Dawson: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: Wanted to upvote, but accidentally downvoted. Now fixed.

Answer (score 16):

## JS (ES6), 67 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135394/65836))

```
(x,y)=>{while(x!==y||Object.is(x, y)||!isFinite(x)||!isFinite(y));}
```

I *think* i didn't mess up, it might have an easy solution that I didn't see.

I appreciate any feedback, this is one of my first posts

> `(+0, -0)` Yep, js has a negative 0

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135394/65836)

Comment: I realize now that I don't need to check if `x` and `y` are finite, but I won't edit since it was already cracked. Could have been 38 bytes

Answer (score 12):

## Python 3.4, (40 bytes) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135503/64047)

```
def f(x):
  while(x==x or not x==x):pass
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135503/10894)

Comment: I feel like you should have stored `x==x` in a variable called `to_be`, so you could make a Hamlet reference.

Comment: @PeterCordes But that would have made the answer uncrackable

Comment: @ppperry: yeah, I noticed that after I looked at the crack.  :P

Comment: wait a moment -- it still would be crackable -- but in a different way

Answer (score 10):

## Javascript (NOT node.js)

```
x=>{while(x+"h");}
```

The desired submission doesn't use throw.

Hint for desired crack:

> The desired submission doesn't overwrite `.toString()`, or use `Set()` either.

Desired crack:

> `Object.create(null)`

Comment: [Correct crack link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135474/65836) (not mine, just a link to Dom Hasting's answer)

Comment: [Cracked#2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135485#135485) Cracked without using `throw` (still gives an error though)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135547/72664) again without using `throw`, I believe for real this time as Grant Davis' didn't work for me. Still `TypeError`s.

Comment: @HaumedRahmani My code works for me: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/7/CNi@1XCE4tURD05qrwtauujwjMydVo0JbKUNJ07r2/38A)

Comment: Seems you're creating the function but not assigning or calling it. If you replace your solution with anything else in that example it'll end just as quickly.

Comment: You could do `x=>{try{for(;x+"h";)}catch(e){for(;;)}}` so that any errors will result in an endless loop so missing prototype function errors (or any errors) will result in an endless loop.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135632/72685) without using any `toString` trickery :)

Comment: I don't think [the `+` specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) lets us turn `x+"h"` falsy (unless `"h"` became `new String("h")`), and I don't think it's possible to overwrite `while` since it's a keyword - I'm really looking forward to the solution to this.

Comment: [Added a `toPrimitive` solution that doesn't use `throw`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135632/72685) - it's almost identical to a `toString` override tho. I can't really see a solution that's notably different from the existing ones - I'm looking forward to seeing the intended solution.

Comment: Is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135843/967) the desired solution?

Comment: [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135874/4199) only works in the browser, not sure why it does though :D

Comment: In fact you can use any symbol, but apparently it is not the intended  solution..

Comment: [Added cross origin solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135632/72685) (heavily inspired by @jadkik94, but works everywhere and is more explicit about what it does) :)

Comment: @ecatmur no, but nice job!

Comment: @programmer5000 `Symbol()`

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 75 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135526/9498)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){char c[9];while(1){scanf("%8s",c);printf(c);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQl1aa4JCUzXy/Djiszr0QhNzEzT0OzOjkjsUghOdoy1ro8IzMnVcNQs7o4OTEvTUNJ1aJYSSdZ07qgCKg8TQPIqq39/x8A)

I've never posted in a cops-n-robbers before. Hopefully this isn't *too* obvious.

Solution:

> An input of "%s" makes this segfault. There are several other ones that can be used; all of them are `printf` specifiers like "%n"
>  
>  This is the classic `printf` vulnerability. Simply put, the format string comes straight from user input, so any `printf` specifiers get passed through, unsafely.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135526/31957).

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (in Browser), 79 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135709/44718)

```
x=>{try{for(;x||x!=null||x!=void 0||x===null||x===void 0;);}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

You should run it in a recent browser (like latest Firefox ESR, latest Firefox, latest Chromium). Running on old browsers (like Netscape 2, IE 4) do not count.

Note: Halted by browser due to time out do not count a halt here.

Always be careful not crash your browser when testing this codes, and happy robbing ^_^

> document.all

Comment: Can i use setTimeout?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков You may call this function with any parameter. But it seems use `setTimeout` as parameter do not works.

Comment: idea is to do `var key=(()=>{setTimeout(args);return null})()` and then `crackme(key)`

Comment: seems like cheating

Comment: can i redefine `Function.prototype`?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков Not sure what you want to do... Just be sure that the given function is called, any codes should be fine.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135709/61875)

Answer (score 7):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (cracked by Vicente Gallur Valero), 65 bytes

```php
<?php
parse_str($argv[1],$_);
while(!$_['(-0_0)> deal with it']);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CrILGoODW@uKRIQyWxKL0s2jBWRyVe05qrPCMzJ1VDUSU@Wl1D1yDeQNNOISU1MUehPLMkQyGzRD1W0/r///9p@fm2SYlFAA)

Harder than it may look. Edited to be possible on TIO, at the cost of a bunch of bytes. Takes input via `$argv[1]`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135605/72675)

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135846/62393)

```
↑ε∞←ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9odXNr///ihpHOteKInuKGkMO4////MTIz)

A bit of explanation, since this language is still pretty new:

`←ø` gets the first element of an empty list: this returns a value which can assume any type, be it a concrete type or a function, which will then be applied to the input. `∞` creates an infinite list composed by copies of the previous result (which in most cases will mean a list of infinite zeroes). `↑ε` takes elements from this list as long as they are "small" i.e. their absolute value is ≤1; on an infinite list of zeroes this will never stop.

Comment: @Veedrac that was actually my intended solution

Comment: Well, then, [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135846/21194)

Answer (score 6):

## Bash 4.2, 14 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135797/12012))

Let's try this again.

```bash
let ${1,,}
yes
```

This doesn't work on TIO, which uses Bash 4.3. Input is via command-line arguments.

On Linux and with gcc installed, Bash 4.2.53 can be downloaded and built as follows.

```
curl -sSL https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.53.tar.gz | tar xz
cd bash-4.2.53
./configure
make -j
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135797/21194) Basically ended up reading the source.

Answer (score 5):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 4 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135368/58826))

```
[1+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/2lA79v9/AA)

Suuuper easy, but <s>let's see how long it takes</s>

Answer:

> `-1`, or any number less than `0`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135368/58826).

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes ([cracked by Eric Duminil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135516/6828))

```ruby
0until(3.send(gets)==5rescue p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/36A0ryQzR8NYrzg1L0UjPbWkWNPW1rQotTi5NFWhQPP/fwA)

Note that this needs to be run in an environment where there's no trailing newline in the result of `gets`, or else it's impossible to make it halt (I think) since anything ending in a newline will error and hit the rescue.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135516/65905)

Comment: Nice one by the way! No method in `3.methods` returns `5` or exits the loop.

Comment: Darn! I discovered the solution as well independently, but I was too focused on making it equal `5` to think that the correct answer would involve the function that it did...

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, 25 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135641/21194))

```
export "$1"=help
/bin/yes
```

Inspired by Dennis'. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7WiIL@oREFJxVDJNiM1p4BLPykzT78ytfj///8A)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135641/48931)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 78 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135384#135384)) ([Cracked with Intended Solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135383#135383))

```
^
1
+`^1(1+)
$1¶$&
s`(?<=^|¶)(1+)(?=¶)(?!.*¶\1+$)

¶(?!1+$)

^(1+)¶\1$

+`1
11
```

Was pretty fun to write, hope it's fun to crack

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/jsuQSzshzlDDUFuTS8Xw0DYVNa7iBA17G9u4mkPbNEHCGva2IJa9op7WoW0xhtoqmlxch7YB@RBmHEgNSEKFC2iSIZeh4f//AA)

Cracked with an unintended solution and the intended solution within a minute of each other.  One posted first, one commented first.

Intended solution:

> 11111 
>  or the unary representation of n-1 where n is any perfect number

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135384/34718)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135383/41805)

Comment: So whose crack counts? (I posted the crack first, but mbomb007 commented first)

Comment: @Cowsquack both

Answer (score 4):

## Node.js, 23 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135560/71612))

```
var crackme =
i=>{while({[i]:NaN}){}}
```

*Grant Davis* solution

> `{__proto__:null}`

My solution

> `{"toString":process.exit}`

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135560/38941)

Comment: @GrantDavis good job) Your solution works i browser too. I thought to surround it with try-catch, but refused this idea, to make a pretty code.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash 4.2, 10 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135625/31625))

```bash
let $1
yes
```

This doesn't work on TIO, which uses Bash 4.3. Input is via command-line arguments.

On Linux and with gcc installed, Bash 4.2.53 can be downloaded and built as follows.

```
curl -sSL https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.53.tar.gz | tar xz
cd bash-4.2.53
./configure
make -j
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135625/21194) You led me 'round in circles thinking this was shellshock related and linking me to a patched version :P. Count the unintended crack as petty revenge ;).

Comment: Heh, not quite what I was going for. I posted a hardened version if you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 99 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135673#135673)

```
s->{try{Integer i=Integer.parseInt(s),c=i+32767;i+=32767;for(;i!=c;);}catch(Throwable t){for(;;);}}
```

This is a lambda of the type `Consumer<String>`.

Ungolfed:

```
s -> {
    try {
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s), c = i + Short.MAX_VALUE;
        i += Short.MAX_VALUE;
        while (i != c) ;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        while (true) ;
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4/b8IwEMV3f4rrZotiVa1UBmOWTgxM7YYYjDHh0sSO7AtVFeWzp06T8Jb78zvde6W5m3VonC8v3wPWTYgEZd7JlrCS19ZbwuDlR/CprV1UjDXtuUILtjIpwcGgh44xyJpBIkO53ANeoM6Yf1JEXxxPYGKRRL6GWcvT7XSxg9EO9IMvGtJ611H87faeXOEioJ472ZiYXB54Es9W4@rtdfO@UbjSU3MNkSt80lYJ1VtD9sa/bjH8mHPlgET3z0fWD4uZetiPaaSx1jXEx@jHl5OYaM8Y64c/) (note that the test program will crash on empty input, but the lambda itself would not!) (also, use 'arguments' not 'input' on TIO, as the test program uses arguments, not STDIN)

Intended Answer:

> -32767;
>  This works because Java keeps has two integer types, `int` and `Integer`. `Integer` is an object that wraps `int`. Also, Java keeps an cache of `Integer`s that box `-127` through `127`. The `!=` operator checks for identity, so through some un-boxing and auto-boxing any number `x` where `x + 32767` is in `[-127, 127]` will end up being the same `Integer` object from the cache, and thus `i != c` will be false.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135673/21194)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 140 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135862#135862))

```
n,i;f(){float x,y,z;for(scanf("%d %d",&n,&z,x=y=0);~((int)x-(int)(1/sqrt(y*2)));x*=(1.5-y*x*x))y=(x=z)/2,i=n-((*(int*)&x)/2),x=*(float*)&i;}
```

Hopefully there aren't too many not-even-close-to-the-intended-inputs that make it halt, but let's see.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5Bi8IwEIXv/opQsMyERFdhTyEHQcHDHjzsHwix0UCbdtMKScX96WZnO5d5fI@Z96y8WVtKEF45wKdrezOxJLKYlesjjNYEB9X6ytbXStRB1LNIOusPVL8APkyY5LJgtx1/4gSZ7xFRJa5ht/mUmSeeELOGpGfc7oXXQQLw/xuOdSKE9JDDEkzEq1chj3XGB8DVc8VoqJlaxBDJoz7nw9f36VgRfZXLY2K5f0Tmw0Dy3sRGsKFtzNhs3ta15jYW2XZ/)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135862/21194)

Answer (score 3):

### Java: 1760 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135401/60951))

I feel it's too mean to golf this one, so I just obfuscated the variable names, and made it 'messy'. As a matter of fact it's so mean, that I'm going to post hints over time, just so I may see it cracked.

Hint 1: this has theoretically infinite valid inputs, but there is one that is the most 'Correct'

```java
public class Main {

	public static void main(String[] a) {
		try {
			while (a.length < 2) {
				int i = 0;
			}
			boolean invalid = 1 < 0;
			char l = '_';
			char h = '-';
			char[] DATATWO = a[0].toCharArray();
			char[] DATATOW = a[1].toCharArray();
			int length = DATATOW.length;
			if (DATATWO.length != length) {
				invalid = 1 > 0;
			}
			int transmissionStartIndex = 0;
			for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
				if (DATATWO[i] == l && DATATOW[i] == l) {
					transmissionStartIndex = i;
					break;
				}
			}
			int DATAONE = 0, reg = 0;
			boolean read = 1 < 0, full = 0 < 1;
			int bytes_read = 0;
			for (int i = transmissionStartIndex; i < length; i++) {
				if (DATATOW[i] == l && DATATOW[i + 1] == h) {
					bytes_read++;

					if (bytes_read == 8) {
						read = DATATWO[i] == h;
					} else if (bytes_read == 9) {
						invalid = (DATATWO[i] == h || invalid);
						System.out.println(invalid);
					} else if (bytes_read == 18) {
						System.out.println(invalid);
						invalid = (DATATWO[i] == h || invalid);
						if (invalid) {
							System.out.println("i36 " + DATATWO[i] + " " + h);
						}
						full = 1 > 0;
					} else if (bytes_read < 8) {
						DATAONE += (DATATWO[i] == h ? 1 : 0) << (7 - bytes_read);
					} else if (bytes_read < 18) {
						reg += (DATATWO[i] == h ? 1 : 0) << (8 - (bytes_read - 9));
					} else if (bytes_read > 18) {
						invalid = 1 > 0;
					}
					System.out.println(a[0]);
					System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", " ") + "|");
					System.out.println(a[1]);
				}
			}

			while (!(Integer.toHexString(DATAONE).equals("0x2b") && (read)
					&& Integer.toHexString(reg).equals("0xa6"))) {

				System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
				try {
					Thread.sleep(1);
				} catch (InterruptedException e) {
					e.printStackTrace();
				}
			}

		} catch (Exception e) {
			while (true) {
			}
		}

	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVRT9swEH5Of8WRB0gUGjVMYmy0TGhDGg@MByrxwKrKTU1jcJPMcUqr0d/enRM7SWmgmqLW9vn8fd/dOZcnsiDdJKXx0/R5s@mk@YSzEEJOsgxuCIvhb6djaWsmicRhkbApzHHPuZOCxbOHERAX/SxLilUxWi8R4xQc4nMaz2QEfTgpPSyLxRIYDKB3rpZr9TdJEk5JDCxeEI7YAwjwROkQRkQAR9PR@Kg2RMrQrQ0o4cfl8HJ4f4sb5KE38mXyHe2XQpCV4@743d4XfkGbnxKoZQ@Mt46j3H8ER5OZ8A4G@kQdZB3JRTNUBS4FibM5yzKWxHeSCHkdT@mySsljIsCps4RDX6Pj3PMqilrGAxvBACXA4aERbEzG23qXlJ2XDhNByXM5X2/JVYi3v66UmGMQdFYJNWXDg1XNjuEx56pcPVwFVT4nK0mzsXZsCbNd3f7Y60C3YgcPgsJcFcSqFXjeeae0KZimsgGcVf6WFrud4kgnaw2UZxR2Ab7UAPUdeFOnCF5fzV13NaB1t8oknftJLv0UXyrJY@eNy7ucQUP1fpj/1KXojK1iaaOx2adTsDHzDVAPDcoUVXBrPepbUr8d78XXb9bEXEWvRfs3BPsKPRf6fXA@Q7dx59w9DMFW2Wf74c8QvgnRxbp/THKxRdLWHqrctORWdTSD37Id0xcoW3ExLRodG7m@oCknIXXs3z37WJXCVRV5tT@AUj3R3eoCjXZ@4FzHks6owK75ky41pS6K69M/OeGZY/eWJxOkwhfSKbJfkuGy7TTmu3mSnNqu6xYfnXaB2hTmQtBYDtmc3jDOWeaYAlTfIMsaRorfzzilqROYsCAkMoygiEWIPJV0erUMaSqx9wCtikRLSuxG4fNQqDTu5KWC2j2vMyZFbizqmDq17qw7m81mPPa7vvmZp1yP9Rx9uvuefw)

Comment: Two empty arguments seem to work

Comment: Also, mind adding a tio link? I think all you'd need to do is change main to Main

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135401/18984), apart from a bug.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135403/26600) - no version specific bug.

Answer (score 3):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 18 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135419/44998)

```
1+[#£-0!e>:$_1>|]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fUDta@dBiXQPFVDsrlXhDu5rY//8B)

Liiiitle bit harder than the last one, I'll start writing a *real* one after this

> The answer is 163

Comment: Man, this is probably the only surviving submission atm. Note: `i` doesn't work.

Comment: Warning: this is actually 19 bytes (`£`). And why doesn't `-1` work? This is tricky.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's 17 characters and 18 bytes.

Comment: @totallyhuman I swear I had read "19 UTF-8 bytes, 18 chars" (userscript is enabled)...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135419/34388)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 41 bytes ([Hacked & Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135432/58563))

*Edit: fixed to prevent it from crashing when given no input at all (thanks @totallyhuman for noticing)*

---

Several solutions probably exist, but the expected one is relatively simple.

```js
(x=0)=>{for(;~x/x.length**3!=-2962963;);}
```

Intended solution:

> "8e7" (a number in scientific notation passed as a string)
>  Because: ~"8e7"/"8e7".length**3 =   -80000001/3**3 = -80000001/27 = -2962963

Comment: No input works on this one too, but I don't want to bother cracking it like that... Unless, that's the intended solution. :P

Comment: @totallyhuman Well, it's _not_ the intended solution. :-)

Comment: Hacked https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135432/71612

Comment: Update: got intended 3 bytes long solution

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 18 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135461/65836))

```javascript
x=>{while(x+"h");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66PCMzJ1WjQlspQ0nTuvZ/moaB5n8A)
Answer:

> `new Buffer(268435440)` throws an error when `.toString`ed.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135461/65836)

Comment: Also, `Symbol()` would work.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>36</s> 26 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135649/60043))

```
#0[#;$IterationLimit=∞]&
```

A very short loop `#0[#;∞]` that will just keep running itself over and over until it crashes your kernel... (The `$IterationLimit` is just to make sure you get stuck forever for most inputs).

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox!](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) - if you are stuck in an infinite loop, you can wait until you time out, or you can press the square "abort evaluation" icon to the left of the notebook title `(unnamed)`.

**NOTE**: this function changes your `$IterationLimit` settings.

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135649/8478)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + Utils (Cracked by Dennis), 74 bytes

I hope you enjoy tar, because it's the only utility you can use.

```bash
cp /bin/tar .
env -i PATH=$PWD I=$? /bin/bash -r -c "$1"
while :;do :;done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7lAQT8pM0@/JLFIQY8rNa9MQTdTIcAxxMNWJSDcRcHTVsUeoiAJqFxBt0hBN1lBScVQias8IzMnVcHKOiUfTOSl/v//PzU5I19BPTK/VKE8MydHIS@/RCG1ODmxIFVRHQA)

#### Intended crack

> `tar -cf --checkpoint=1 --checkpoint-action=exec="/bin/kill $I" .`

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135597/12012)

Comment: @Dennis Nice! I posted my intended crack, which was a bit more complex.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 118 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135755/38550))

```
using System;_=>{while(1>0){try{if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Type.GetType(Console.ReadLine()))!=null)break;}catch{}}}
```

I don't expect this to last too long but it is more awkward than it appears to be.

> Basically any Nullable classes full name works but it is awkward to find out as it looks like the below :
> `` System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ``
> An easier way to find this string out is to do `typeof(int?).FullName`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135755/15738)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 73 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136014#136014)!)

```
q=>{r=(n,i=0)=>i>1e3?n:r(n*16807%(2**31-1),i+1);while(r(q)!=627804986){}}
```

Not wanted solutions: brute force. Desired crack involves math.

Note that there are many solutions (4194304) because of modulo.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136014/21194)

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 3, 14 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136754/61563))

```
while !false{}
```

To solve this, put your code before or after this statement.

- Your solution must:

  - keep this statement intact, without modifying its code
  - actually let this statement run

    - Simply commenting it out, calling `fatalError()`, etc. before it doesn't count.
  - modify the behavior of this statement to prevent it from looping forever
- The solution does not involve crashing the program.

Comment: I don't know Swift, but I think adding a timer before this code to exit after a few seconds would meet the criteria.

Comment: @Yimin heh, clever, but it doesn't modify the semantics of this statement, which is what I was really looking for when I said "modifies the behaviour of this statement"

Comment: Are you sure that the solution works? The interpreter is yelling `ambiguous semantics` at me.

Comment: @Dopapp that's what I thought would happen in my previous attempt. For some reason, it's legal to redefine new infix operators with the same type signatures as those that already exist, but attempting to do the same with a unary operator throws a compile time ambiguity error. This is intentional, and I'm sure I have a working solution

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136754/21194)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 170 bytes [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136642#136642)

```
>>,>,>,>,>,[-----------<-<+<--<--->>>>]<++<<+<++[----->+<]>[----------------->+++++++<]>[----->>+<<]>>[-<->]<[--->++++++<]>[--->+<]+>-[-----------------<+>]<[-->-<]>+[+-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxLCoAwEEMPFHODkIuULlQQRHAheP46pfUDJoshmUemY1z35Zy3UuzhduIrUVA9pENZgKIBGmQo@8uz103P0wFGiCTGSHqZjtQhmP8pofFmkEhgLuUC)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You could save 11 bytes by removing the newlines from your code.

Comment: I forgot it was code golf, thanks!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136642/69850)

Comment: Valid solution! I estimate there are quite a bit of them. 
For anyone solving/brute-forcing, the intended one is [a-z].

Comment: For each 4 characters, there are exactly 1 value of the last character makes the program halt. Therefore there are 256^4 = 4294967296 solutions assuming you can enter `nul` into brainfuck. BTW you can remove two first `>` save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Jerry: Edited in intended input.

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES6), 23 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135381/58974))

```
x=>{while(!x||x>="\n");}
```

Fairly easy, but not that easy.

*-1 byte thanks to Step Hen, -3 thanks to a mistake pointed out by Step Hen*

Comment: @StepHen You can't assume input is an a varible, but lambda functions like this are allowed. While is a block statement, meaning it has to be wrapped in `{}` when in an arrow functions.

Comment: @StepHen oh oops!

Comment: That confused the crap out of me. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135379/65836)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135381/58974)

Comment: Am I missing something or does the Braingolf solution work here too?

Comment: @Neil you're right, it would, negative numbers are `>=` strings, TIL

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 2 bytes ([Cracked 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135391/41805)) ([Cracked 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135395/30164))

```
:A
```

Note that this will quickly hit the 128 KiB output limit on TIO, causing it to stop, but when run locally it will loop forever, except on the input that breaks it. Finding that input should be fairly easy. Until you do, `:A` will keep sticking its triangular tongue out at you.

Note also that this *should* be just `A` but I broke implicit modes last night. On older interpreter versions `A` would work fine.

Cracks:

> Empty input/newline on input is a valid crack. However, barring that, by passing multiple (space separated) inputs to the program, you'll terminate it (if you give 2) or error out (if you give 3 or more).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/38rx//@S1OISAA)

Comment: [Cracked?](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/38rx/38A) (Errors out with empty input)

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135391/41805)

Comment: @crackers yep, that's a valid crack. I'll give my upvote to someone who finds the non-empty-input crack though.

Comment: [Cracked (the intended way?)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135395/30164)

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES6), <s>81</s> 75 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135414/65836))

```
x=>eval("for(var i=0;i<1/0;i+="+(x.slice?Math.abs(Number(x))+50||1:1)+");")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBDsIgEADArxhOuyGtcPAioi9o/7AgRBq0DSDhwN/ROcxGlbJN4SjTZ3@64fVo@u4qRWB@T1ApnYIWKtzk@T/XjEObcwzWPRYqr5lMhvX7Ni5BQ@QX0bu8SuQMFcPhQeD4AQ)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135414/65836)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135519/31957)

```javascript
x=>{while(!x||x.__proto__);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66PCMzJ1VDsaKmpkIvPr6gKL8kPz5e07r2f5pGXmlOjuZ/AA)

Know of anything truthy that dosen't have the `__proto__` property?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135519/31957)

Comment: I'm curious, what was the intended solution? Or do you feel like waiting for someone to find it?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien trying to use the intended ans on something else.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135520/65836) (not by me, user with not enough rep to comment)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135636)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (44 characters per TIO): [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135567/7944)

```
while 1:
 try:
  x = input()
 except:
  pass
```

Updated TIO Link to correct for a more trivial example than intended from code golfing:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/vzwjMydVwdCKS6GkqBJIKlQo2Cpk5hWUlmhocimkViSnFpSAhAsSi4v//wcA)

Comment: Dunno if you were trying to golf this or not, but for future whatever, you can switch tabs and spaces for indentation to save bytes (in your case, two spaces -> tabs) and you can remove spaces around `=`. In case you, or anyone reading, didn't know.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: Fixed the pass bug.  I'm not sure about the cracked part: I had a different set of inputs in mind that would work from TIO or another thing that did python myapp < myinputs ; can you embed a control-C in a useful fashion in a text file?  From linux, almost anything can be terminated by doing control-z and kill -9 %1 so I'm not sure where the dividing line is.

Comment: @StepHen thanks; I hadn't realized this was codegolf until after I posted it and my first attempt to golf it a bit ended up making it trivially easy to break

Comment: Let's say "not cracked" and wait for a better one then!  
...For readers - I am retracting `exit()` <newline> `<ctrl>C` (or *nix equivalent) as per [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135530/53748) in light of a better one...

Comment: ...pretty sure you can replace `pass` with `1` though.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135567/21194) The "possibly" was irking me.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, 187 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135534/64047)

```
def f(x):
 t="""def t():
 def t():
  while t:pass
  {}

 t()
t()"""
 if type(x) != str or chr(10) in x:
  while t:pass
 try:t=compile(t.format(x),'m','exec')
 except:
  while t:pass
 exec(t)
```

Forgot that \r also counts as newline. [Fixed Version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135606/64047)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135534/53748).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 45 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135702/45032), [and again!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135704/967))

A bit of an odd one, and probably easier than the last, but it's shorter.

```
def T(x,t=type):
 while t(x)is t or T(t(x)):0
```

Pass one argument to `T` by appending code to this program. That argument may be initialized imperatively. [This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135520/21194) is the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: This seems easily crackable by specifying a second argument.

Comment: Could somebody please explain why it doesn't end up with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`? Leaving a `print("Calling T with %s" % x)` as the first line of `T` and calling `T(3)` only outputs `Calling T with 3\nCalling T with <class 'int'>` but uses 100% CPU.

Comment: @Dennis It's a one argument function. _\*looks both ways\*_. I wouldn't count such an answer in the spirit of the question. Passing 12 arguments halts too.

Comment: @EricDuminil Consider what happens if `t(x)is t`. Remember `or` short-circuits. And would you look at that, `t(int)is t`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135702/45032)

Comment: Or was [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135704/967) what you're looking for?

Comment: Wow, I need to step up my game! Excellent work to you both.

Comment: I have to admit, I would never have come up with that answer myself without looking in the [CPython test suite](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/test/leakers/test_selftype.py)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135611/44718)

```javascript
x=>{for(;!(x**x==x&&x!=1&&x+x>x););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q46Lb9Iw1pRo0JLq8LWtkJNrULR1hBIalfYVWhaa1rX/rdO0zAx0vwPAA)

This one should be quite easy ^_^

Solution by Vicente Gallur Valero

> 1.00000001

My Solutions:

> 'Infinity' or '-1'

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135611/72675)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, 203 bytes ([Cracked with Intended Solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135759/72711) and [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135754/72711))

```
def f(x):
 t="""def t():
 def t():
  while t:pass
  {}

 t()
t()"""
 import re
 if type(x) != str or re.search(r"\s",x,re.UNICODE):
  while t:pass
 try:t=compile(t.format(x),'m','exec')
 except:
  while t:pass
 exec(t)
```

There is actually a third way to crack it

My Answer:

> f("t=t")
>  Python decides at compile time if a variable is local or not by checking if it is assigned anywhere in the function
>  So even if the statement is never executed it still changes the behaviour of the function(in this case causing an UnboundLocalError because it is never assigned)

Comment: I won't resubmit @JonathanAllan cracked version just by changing `'\r'` to `chr(12)`, but you might want to check for that also.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135759/10894)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135634#135634)

```r
f=function(x){eval(x);x=T;while(x){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM6tSwxB0hbV9iGWJdnZOakggRra/@naVTYKiUmJacoaf4HAA)

Intended solution (basically the same as the cracked version):

> `x=T<-F`

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135634/21194)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>52</s> 46 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135794/44718))

```javascript
x=>{try{(!(x*1)||x*1)&&0()}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66pKiyWkNRo0LLULOmBkSqqRloaNYmJ5YkZ2ikalan5RdpWFtrWtfW/k/TUMrMKygtUdL8DwA)

Intended:

> // break excluded middle: 
>  {valueOf:()=>this.q?0:this.q=1}

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135794/44718)

Comment: [Cracked in a less clever way!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135842/9365)

Comment: @DomHastings that's just mean

Comment: Yeah, I thought so!  Enjoyed playing with it though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135849/20080), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135850/20080)

```
##.vz
```

[Code](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%23.vz&debug=0)

I believe there's (essentially) only a single solution.

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135849/34388)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135850/21194)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 63 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135837/38550))

```
a=>{while(1>0)if(string.IsInterned(new string(a))!=null)break;}
```

Compiles to a `Action<char[]>`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xC8IwEIX3/IrnlgyKzrUFxw6C4CgOMU1tsL1IklqK9LfX1mJF/Kbjfe/gTvllZcn2fe0NXXFsfdBVxJgqpfc4sCfDgA8yGIWHNRn20hAX73iSIzsVjKWtKqQ7nRPkiCERJ7P/NkeawpQafIMEa/FjRkwO7oMbzlmlPqWgHemMk24wpVwKgUUMqsvyf3vk4rS8RbPqhn8@c85bWzsYutcBhXZaTL2OdX3/Ag)

> An empty array and `null` all seem to work. This is because `string.Empty`, or `""`, is always interned.

Comment: Hmm, based on my knowledge of `IsInterned`, it returns true for an `Interned` string, which is a string that is a string literal within the code, or has been interned with `Intern`, this means you're abusing some undocumented behaviour of `IsInterned` somehow, because there are no string literals defined.

Comment: @Mayube It returns the `string` not a `bool` which I found odd myself. I suppose it isn't as intuitive as you'd think it would be though.

Comment: that's what I meant sorry, `IsInterned()!=null` returns true if the string is Interned, and false otherwise.

Comment: @Mayube It's been cracked, I thought this one was harder than that.

Comment: Aaah, my problem is I was thinking input from STDIN, not just argument to the method :P

Comment: @Mayube Yeah :) That's why I added the TIO link.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, 43 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136336/42854)

```
func f(i:Int){let p=0;while i==p||i != p{}}
```

Call with `f(i: /*your input here*/)`

More readable:

```
func gandalf(input: Int) {
    let password = 0
    while input == password || input != password {
        print("You shall not pass!")
    }
    
    print("nvm")
}
```

Call with `gandalf(input: /*your input here*/)`

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/JjlD/2)

I affirm that I have a working crack for this.

Comment: The code at the "Try it here!" link does not match the one in the post. I don't know whether it matters - I have no idea how swift works.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Yes it does, it matches the ungolfed code (for the robbers' convenience, of course :P)

Comment: @Alexander It doesn't; `password` is inlined.

Comment: @Veedrac Oh, true!

Comment: Can the crack be a runtime error? If so, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136237/42854). I am guessing this is not what you had in mind, though.

Comment: @Dopapp I'll concede to a runtime error, but only if you cause it within my function. You just caused a runtime error before my function runs, in a convoluted way. You may as well just have `fatalError()`ed

Comment: @Alexander, yeah that’s fair I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Dopapp When you think about it, most of these programs could be "cracked" with `exit(1)`, `throw new Exception()`, `fatalError()`, etc. I guarantee that there is a way to run this code that gets it to halt, that does *not* involve crashing it

Comment: Is this what you were going for? [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136336/42854).

Comment: @Dopapp Nice! That was very close to what I had in mind. I didn't know you could redefine existing overloads (e.g. the `(Int, Int) -> Bool` variant of `==`)

Answer (score 2):

## CPython 2.7, <s>96</s> <s>93</s> 100 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135995/8611)

There are so many loopholes in python! It is really hard to write code which can't be manipulated or produce vastly unexpected results.

```
def f(x):
 try:
  s=str(x)
  [c for c in s if c not in'x.']and 0/0
  exec(s)
 finally:
  while(1):1
```

Not too hard, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm new to code golf so I am not sure if I need to make this a function or if stand alone code like this is OK. Can anyone point me at some rule or clarify this for me?

Comment: on my machine, `del str` immediately throws NameError regardless of the input I give.

Comment: @tbodt So it gets caught in the while loop at the end right? I wasn't sure if the rules of this challenge allows the robbers to override `str`, so I did `del str` just in case. So if you don't override it, you get caught in the loop. I would ask the OP but I don't have comment priv yet.

Comment: If you write your program as a function, the input would come from function arguments, otherwise it would come from outside the program (e.g. `input()` or `sys.argv`)

Comment: OK, thanks. I made it a function and removed `del str` because I assume that it would be cheating to override `str` since that is not technically input.

Comment: Simplest thing I can come up with is some code that segfaults the interpreter and is carefully constructed to not contain . or x. is there a simpler thing I should be looking for?

Comment: @tbodt Did you mean, "carefully constructed to _only_ contain . or x"? If your `x` contains characters other than `x` or `.` then it will raise `ZeroDivisionError` and go to the infinite loop. But I was able to get it to stop without crashing.

Comment: oh I read the code wrong. hmm

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135995/8611)

Comment: @tbodt Nicely done. That is the solution that I had, except I used `os._exit(0)`

Comment: yours is more portable :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C++](https://isocpp.org/) ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)/[MSVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/)), 62 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136049/967)

```cpp
template<class T,T=T{}>T*f(T t){for(static T*a;!a;(T&)a=t=0);}
```

Tested on Linux and Windows, with and without optimizations enabled. Under MSVC, you may wish to use `#pragma warning(default:4716)`.

> `class T{}T::*t;`
>  
>  A null pointer-to-data-member is (typically, on modern platforms) assigned a numeric value of -1, as opposed to other null pointers, which are assigned a numeric value of 0. This is so that the pointer-to-data-member can store the offset of the data member from the beginning of the class, since this offset could be 0 for the first data member.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCsMgEADAe1@xSaFoaKHnaHLpF/YDy6pFakyIm5Pk7Zb2OAxv2@PN3Jr4ZUsk3nKiUgDvOGE9ZxyCQhBdw7qrIiSRAQcyHRmFN02TTE9tznaNmdPhPNi4Ftk9LfMlZoGFYlYaKgQl2kARN468HgLWQv/aiT/edf1P//LZJQNn@wI)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136049#136049) (Anyone add an explanation for me? I don't know how that works.)

Comment: @user202729 Excellent! Added an explanation in the spoiler.

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js, 129 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136290/64949)

```
q=>{try{v=require("vm");c=v.createContext();new v.Script(String.prototype.toString.apply(q)).runInContext(c)}catch(a){}for(;;){}}
```

Unwanted: tampering with require/vm (eg `require=1;q()`)

Comment: which version of Node?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136290/15842)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136520#136520)

```python
def f(o):
 while bool(o)==bool(o):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1/TikuhPCMzJ1UhKT8/B8i3tYUyrAz@p2moJ@UkZqhrKigrVOaXFilk5hWUlihkpBal/gcA)

Not too hard...

Intended solution (ungolfed, 'cause screw it):

> `class LOL:
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.lol = True
>
>     def __bool__(self):
>         self.lol = not self.lol
>         return self.lol
>
> lol = LOL()
>
> f(lol)`

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136520/68942)

Answer (score 2):

### #Batch, <sub><s>26 24</s></sub> 28 bytes - [Cracked(Unintened)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136559#136559)

Unfortunately, TIO doesn't support batch, so you will need to try on a command prompt.

```
:L
set/pp=
echo("%p%"
goto l
```

---

The unintended solution:

> ```
> "&&exit
> ```
>
> (Note the trailing space!)
>  This undoes the quotes in `echo("` and execute the `exit` command. Actually, the `exit` command can be changed to lots of other commands that causes an exit.

The intended solution:

> *Hint: The intended solution does not use `&&`, but uses variable expansion bug.*

Comment: You should not reveal the inputs it crashes on... That's the whole point of the challenge.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Change is in.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh well. I shouldn't change the code.

Comment: I deleted my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll let someone else crack it.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136559/69850). I wonder how can this last 3 hours without being cracked...

Comment: @user202729 seriously?! Let me test this on my machine

Comment: Does the intended one use `&&`?

Comment: @user202729 Nope. It uses some sort of random variable expansion. It is very long and confusing.

Comment: Is it possible to pass `/v` (enable delayed expansion) to cmd? And I suppose `|` (pipe) and `&`, `||` are also not allowed.

Comment: Do you mean in my solution?

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 91 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136681#136681)

```
x=input()
try:y=len(x)<10and'*'not in x and len(str(eval(x)))==307
except:y=0
while not y:0
```

`raw_input` for Python 2.

No one found the intended answer but the solutions found were very creative and impressive.

A hint for the intended answer is:

> it consists of only letters.

The intended answer is:

> `copyright`

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136558/48931)

Comment: @Sisyphus Very clever. I've shortened the length limit so that won't work any more.

Comment: Probably not what you had in mind. Still, it's [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136578#136578) on my system.

Comment: @EricDuminil nice, and a surprising coincidence, but not what I had in mind. I've changed the length limit again. This is the real one now, I promise! Also the intended answer does work on both python 2 and 3 (surprisingly) at least on my system.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136681/16385). I had another answer too that did fit in the original length limit, but not in the edited one: `"_".__mul__(307)`.

Comment: @hvd well done! Still not what I had in mind but I have to give you this. I've edited in my answer plus a hint.

Comment: Ah, nice, sorry to mess it up! Eric Duminil was much closer to your intended answer than I was.

Comment: @EricDuminil see what the intended answer was. It's shocking that your answer worked.

Comment: @AlexHall: I simply tested `.__doc__` on every word with 4 letters or less. There were 2 others between 300 and 315.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137046/48934)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript ES6 (Node.js >= 6.0)](https://tio.run/##fY8xa8MwEIX/SjffgSqaNeVcOmTr4D2EINSDqL1YqnRVYox/u2u3S2mg2/He9z64N1dd8Tkkve/jK88zQDVMmT8@Q2ZouHKvpUG7W4/dOahytilHjTokNkJHasfLKQjDBh8n01GX43UwiRbIcylILST7HkQoWb4GNWwlFOWec6GeL3cd/ErM6FKSYQtqvHHL2O0fDkTNumye9oet2m8A1nbCRZb5HCs/i7zcWG@r//X@rz3Z2MNPaQRNWH7VPIwVAk7eqT9BxHESWFiEQi1XJ1AQZ7DW4vwF), 326 bytes (Safe)

```javascript
((v,e=require('events').EventEmitter.prototype,l=_=>{while(1);},P=Proxy,p=process)=>(p.kill=p.exit,e.listeners=new P(e.listeners,{apply:(t,c,a)=>a[0]=='exit'?[]:t.apply(c,a)}),e.removeAllListeners=new P(e.removeAllListeners,{apply:(t,c,a)=>a[0]=='exit'?c:t.apply(c,a)}),p.on('exit',l),i=>{try{v(i)}catch(o){}l()}))(s=>eval(s))
```

Much more simplified than [my other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136294/42091) was, I'm no longer attempting to obfuscate the approach for the solution, which saved me a lot of bytes. This time around, `process.kill()` won't work.

> `"delete process._events.exit;process.exit()"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBa8MwDIX/Sm@WwDPbtcUdO/S2Q@6lFOMK6k2NPVtzG0J@e5a0G4wVdpP03vtA781VV3wOSR7aeKBxBKiabKaPz5AJFFVqpSg0m3nYnIIIZZNylChdIs12b9f9@RiY4AlXg25sk@Ol08lOJk@loF1DMu@B2SZDlyCaDIci1FIutqXzooFfF927lLhbgmiv3RR228edtWpOquftbinmaoBZHXCCZTrFSi/Mr3fUe@l/vP9LTya2cBM1ow7Tr5K7vkLAwTvxR4jYDwyTF6HYNVXHUBBHUAdiElp8t2D2tyavDax@jvMCqHD8Ag)

Comment: Woah! Nice job!

Comment: It looks like you're the winner, although I was expecting a much shorter code hehe

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 86 bytes (safe)

```
def _(x):exec x
try:(input()or _("while 1:0"))and _("while 1:0")
except:_("while 1:0")
```

I know this is a late answer, but I thought of what I think is an interesting way to do this.

#### Update and explanation:

The answer is

> `_("__import__('os')._exit(0)")`. In Python 2, the `input` function evals its argument before returning the resulting value. In order to bypass the infinite loops, the input string must somehow lead `input` to exit the program without raising an exception. Ordinarily, this should be impossible, because `eval` cannot execute arbitrary code by itself in Python 2. However, the `_` function may be called by a string passed to `eval`, and since `_` is itself a wrapper for the `exec` statement, which *can* execute arbitrary code, this input is able to function by calling `_` with a string containing a call to the `os._exit` function, which exits the program immediately without erroring.
>  Actually, I just noticed that the `_` `exec` wrapper isn't strictly necessary, as `__import__('os')._exit(0)` is technically an expression rather than a statement and thus can be passed to `eval` without a syntax error.
> Regardless, one should never use the `input` function in Python 2, especially in conjunction with a wrapper for `exec`. Use `raw_input` instead and then convert the value to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E - 4 bytes

```
[I#]
```

The answer is easy if you know 05AB1E

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174016/47990)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 108 bytes, [Double](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/226107#226107) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/226106#226106)

```javascript
f=y=>(x=>{for(;typeof y=='string'&&x===x;);})(f['constructor'](`return +[${y.replace(/[^W-`*-0]/g,'')}]`)())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBDoIwEADAr3Aw7K6KeCfLNzw0NTS1JRjTkqUYGsLbq3Odt/maxco0pybElyvFc@YeN@53HwW7lGcXfZWZYUkyhRHqemPmraPuIPQKbAz/WW2KAhoHcWmVUF3Uac83cfPHWIetej6a4dzcdTteAejQAyFR8QgGqPwA)

Fixed a bug that allowed errors...

> My intended solution was `[][+[]]+[]][+[]`. This evaluates to coercing undefined to an integer, which is NaN, and `NaN !== NaN`.

Comment: It seems like for an input like `'a'` it just errors and halts. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @CommandMaster *Slaps face* It should work now.

Comment: Probably not what you meant, but [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226106/16484). Perhaps making sure `y` is treated as a string would make this trickier?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226107/94093), although I am guessing your intended solution was more clever  (edit: ninja'd)

Comment: @EasyasPi Added an explanation.

Comment: @EasyasPi You two had entirely different approaches.

Comment: I've had `0/0` which also works

Comment: @CommandMaster I think the consensus is that you're not allowed to throw errors.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, `0/0` is `NaN` (it was in a string, ["0/0"](https://tio.run/##DclBCoMwEADAr3go7m5bG@@yfsODWCJpIpaSyBqLQXx72rnOe/yOq5F5iZUPL5uz48Qt7tweLgg2MS02uCIxwxpl9hOU5c7Me0PNSeh6MMH/ZzMxCAyoxcZNfHHrL0d6iF0@o7Go@mdX6WtVD2q6A9A5aEKi7BBqVQPlHw))

Comment: @CommandMaster Oh, yes. (List of characters I allowed coming back to bite me)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135393#135393) and [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135406/36398))

```
jU`ttX=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pys0oaQkwvb//5CMzGIFIErMU8jMS8vMyyxJVcjJzy/QU/AvAolnltgDAA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135393#135393), the empty input errors and terminates the program.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Aw. That was not the intended solution, but well done!

Comment: Perhaps I'll find the intended one too

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135406#135406)

Comment: @PunPun1000 That was the intended solution :-) Well done!! `N` also works (it directly means `NaN`)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 37 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135405/41805))

```
x=>{for(;typeof x!=="object"||x;);}
```

Pretty easy. Let's see how long this lasts.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135405/41805) Nooo, SE automatically converted my crack into a comment, I just reverted it now

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135404/65836)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 35 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135412/58826) and [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135413))

I hope that I didn't miss anything ¯\_(ツ)_/¯:

```javascript
x=>y=>{while(!(x>=y&&x<=y&&x!=y));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q7S1q66PCMzJ1VDUaPCzrZSTa3CBkwq2lZqalrX/k/TMNHUsNT8DwA)

Intended solution:

> `{}`, `{}`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135412/58826). Nice job!

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135413)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135449#135449) and [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135451#135451))

```matlab
x=input('');while 1|x,end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/wjYzr6C0RENdXdO6PCMzJ1XBsKZCJzUv5f9/AA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135449/20268)

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135451/48934)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 106 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135418/66833)

```
+?
-1
=?
-1
=?
N
W,+0
+?
+?
+?
>?
-?
V
V
^2
V
=?
N
W,+0
+G
-G
V
=?
N
W,+0
+G
*G
-?
W,+0
+?
>
-24
-?
W,+0
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnkvXkMsWRvpxhetoG3ABRSHIDihhzxUGhHFGQAJJhTuXrju6iJY7SDXMBDsuXSMTuID///8A)

<s>This is really mean, to anyone who tries to crack it. So, uh, have fun!</s> I forgot about empty input!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135418#135418)

Comment: Uh, it doesn't go into an infinite loop as it is (no input).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28834 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135470/65836)

```javascript
y=>{x=y;[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]])+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])+[])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]])))()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZzNSsQwFIWfJbuE4MK11BcJWQzqwLhQUREH8dlr@mfbpEnLgDYt38aB3DQ3Pz3n3pNLfTx8HN7uXk8v71dPz/cP5bEoz8Xt12dxvjHWSGGsNlYZ98dqaUT149rdj2sTurJWJmfretaNoukvxo@LoE/YsW5wjld0nuy12qz8wRuXgx4T/uacdvbhWF1DlrvvDZfNYfh2KV3baBA9cKyUyX1BurLLtg9gBIwbBmPcHjmAxMQnDrqGSvMMgAEwuwDMIGzVLTYezdqQ5nAgB09oQ6gDuSCXUAdgAMxWQ10XxBbhJTnvcKJr74u/bgI4fAQfEcABDIDZtVb1YjpVDrAH9i6scgR7LJaeTnAYyePqwtfv0tffEjHxhsbmPScDJgz5vZve8ehQJ6EZoGFoGM0AYADM1jWDf/MX866kkkgIoAgUkRCXSgjkAfIAioVikQcABsDsTh70sEit0FuNmXk75oGaZ37gGaxsHLRuTDylUJN1HL@sQzkH3oP30GKUc9Br0DA0jF5DrwEY9BrlHKAIFJEQlHOQB1AsFIs8QB4AGOQB5Zy/LOdMfEpbPdUzS95vUurqN29s5gPG@OD5ipggpTdzRcf5ymSiu11W2cxg34JvxrkqIS0hLeGqhGor1ynQMDTMdQrXKQCG6xSqrUARKCIhqLYiD6BYKBZ5gDwAMMgDqq3/8vFcn0eMd5zcASqECskdAAyA2eA/469DmEsKvsujvFblDw)

> Answer is 991, checks for input * 7 == 6937

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135470/58826)

Comment: Should you mention JSFuck in your heading?

Comment: @kamoroso94 JSF is a subset of JavaScript, it's perfectly valid JavaScript, so not really - it's just a (popular) method of obfuscating JavaScript that has a name.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 228 Bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135512#135512) - Fixed)

I was stupid, and this was cracked because I missed a trivial case. Thanks to Jonathan Allan, it's been fixed, and I resubmit it.

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##rY6xDoMgEIZ3noIwQbsUFaQkPIlxaFoTSdqTGEz16ekpDB06drq7L9/9@cMWxwnqlIILs4dI4rxZQlfnISyRCzKs9yFERO/RPwcqbeDMM1G8DGGKHH85dLLtz9BZHMK56pShlaYXN3jQfDZqd6SxuKBVF2sH@tszR1ajrTnSVPF2gHkCi7x@11uZSOkiq7pRujXXP28f)

```
p=print
try:
    n=input()
except:
    while 1:p("i")
try:
    while sum(map(int,n))<1or not(int(n[17]+n[:17])==2*int(n[:18])and int(n[45]+n[18:45])==3*int(n[18:46])and int(n[87]+n[46:87])==5*int(n[46:88])):p("m")
except:
    while 1:p("x")
```

Comment: TIO is an online execution environment for programs. For example, you might post [this link](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSGtNE8jT9OKSwEIyjMyc1IV8vJLFDQy80o08qINzWO186KtgJSmra2RFkTQytAiVlMhMS9FAcI3MQUpMrSwAjKAyoyhykACZigKLcCmmZhZWYDNM4UqBAkATYS6AQQKikAySh6JSpr//wMA "Python 3 – Try It Online") as a way of sharing your answer through the online environment.

Comment: Simple crack would be `n` a string or list of length less than length 17 causing an `IndexError` (this is assuming `n` is already limited to a string or list too).

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135512/53748). Almost certainly not the intended crack, but also without any error raised.

Comment: @JonathanAllan You're right. I meant to restrict it to only positive values. Is it acceptable to edit it to correct my oversight?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, I have not cracked the intended and it seems cool to me - how about [this](https://tio.run/##rY6xDoMgEIZ3noIwQbsUFaQkPIlxaFoTSdqTGEz16ekpDB06drq7L9/9@cMWxwnqlIILs4dI4rxZQlfnISyRCzKs9yFERO/RPwcqbeDMM1G8DGGKHH85dLLtz9BZHMK56pShlaYXN3jQfDZqd6SxuKBVF2sH@tszR1ajrTnSVPF2gHkCi7x@11uZSOkiq7pRujXXP28f) modification? It means it'll be a full program, so only strings ever get in (empty or ctrl-x etc for input - prints "i") and no errors can occur in the evaluation (prints "x").

Comment: @JonathanAllan That seems to do what I intended, but I couldn't have written something like that. Crediting you in the Answer

Comment: EDIT oops [this](https://tio.run/##tY@/DsIgEIf3PgUygTqI/SMh8iCm6dBUkjbagyCN7dPXo@3g4CoL3Md3v9y5KbQW0nl22vkOQhL8pBICugM3BMYTMzbGBUTvtnsaIpRjtKN881b4GnrW145h/xE4vwrrCdgQawaluFQHKBVeXOvzfoVKyIrXcCdrmeXREVLhA610syIovj25ZGWFkktavnkRYB6Pw/X099Aj5fOyIqM3O5DG183DYG7Y4cfpb@cD) you'd best check your intended input works though :)

Comment: Fixed, and verified the expected answer works on this. I'm a better mathematician than i am golfer. Thanks @JonathanAllan

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you!

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? You don't specify.

Comment: @ppperry python 3, and good luck

Comment: @ppperry You're right, it's been corrected.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174697/72137) the fixed version

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 11 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135528/58375)

```
` .iS‘"{".C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z9BQS8z@FHDDKVqJT3n////AwA)

### Cracks:

> `#` A single `#` will cause the `{` to be treated as a function literal, rather than executing it, which avoids the loop.

Comment: Input through arguments?

Comment: Yep. @ConorO'Brien

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135528/31957).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 42 bytes ([Unintended Crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135557#135557) & [Intented Crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135563#135563))

```
def f(x):
    try:x()
    except:7
    while True:7
```

There's an intended solution here, but I'm curious what people will come up with...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0LTiouzpKjSqkJDk4sztSI5taDEypCLszwjMydVIaSoNNXK8P9/AA)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135557/21194)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135563/20260)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (CPython), 50 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135687/967))

```
l=[]
l+=[l]
def l(a,i=id,l=id(l)):
 while i(a)-l:0
```

Hopefully a little bit tricky.

Pass one argument to `l` by appending code to this program. That argument may be initialized imperatively. [This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135520/21194) is the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: What should be the format of the answer? `l(some_object)` or `l(input())`? Right now, not calling `l` is enough for the program to halt :)

Comment: @EricDuminil Pass a single argument to `l`. To avoid needless busywork, you may initialize that argument imperatively, given several other answers already do.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135687/967

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore 64 Basic, 14 bytes: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135767#135767)

```
1INPUTB
2GOTO1
```

Tested using [VICE](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/), but any Commodore emulator should work.

Cracked:

> 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.9

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135767/21194)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (in Node.js), 65 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135561/72664)

```
x=>{try{for(;!x||x!=0||x instanceof Object;);}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66pKiyOi2/SMNasaKmpkLR1gBIKmTmFZck5iWn5qcp@CdlpSaXWGta1yYnliRnaKRqQpSDRGr/W6dpGGj@BwA)

> '0'

Let's try another one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135562/44718

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135561/72664)

Comment: Beat me by one minute.

Comment: @HaumedRahmani aha, not what i want, maybe i will post another cops.... T_T

Comment: @HaumedRahmani OK, just a mirror edit... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135562/44718

Answer (score 1):

## J, 22 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135566/31957)

```
$:@#~^:(0([=[e.{#])#~)
```

This will run forever assuming memory was unlimited, except when given a specific type of input.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135566/31957).

Comment: You might want to suggest the user to test on TIO, this crashed my computer (at least on the windows version)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien It continuously expands the array if it isn't the right input. It will continue to use more memory, and at least on my (Linux) machine, the process gets killed for using too much memory.

Comment: Windows isn't that nice. (Also, the conditional fails for non-positive numbers and floats and infinity as well, all of which error)

Comment: I think I found the intended solution and have edited into my answer

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 85 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135578/44718)

```javascript
x=>{try{for(;!x||x!=0||x instanceof Object||typeof x!='object';);}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoAgFAWvkit1EbgXu0JnsJ9SLjTsE4Z6drPaDLzhMU5f@oS4Hzj6sJpmVUtqyhjvbENkkqRSElGic9j9idqDCXaYF2cAS8H7eGd/0PApKrmsoBE2ZvifeE1t0jIqKG8P)

> `({valueOf:g=>{Object=Number;return 0}})`
>  
>  `({toString:x=>'',__proto__:null})`

Comment: Hmm... I believe everything except number, strings, and booleans are `instanceof Object`, but all of those have `typeof x!='object'`... I guess maybe I'd have to define a custom object?

Comment: @ETHproductions What i tried is a very strange object. but you may also hack it by some strange way on built in objects.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135578/38941)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 50 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135572/21194))

```bash
cd $1
for((;${#PWD}-$(dirname $PWD|wc -c);))
{
:
}
```

Input is via command-line arguments.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzlFQcWQKy2/SEPDWqVaOSDcpVZXRSMlsygvMTdVQQXIrylPVtBN1rTW1OSq5rLiqv3/HwA)

Comment: This may seem TIO specific, but it's not. The intended crack will work on all fresh Linux installs.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135572/21194)

Comment: Well done, that was the intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135801/44998)

```
ɠ#5+¿2«*"ḶİP»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9hbnlmaXj//8mgIzUrwr8ywqsqIuG4tsSwUMK7//8)

Another easy one, hopefully nobody just bruteforces it :(

> -5

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135801/21194)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135654/57013))

```js
a=>{while(!Array.isArray(a)||!a.length);a.map(_=>{for(;;);})}
```

Intended solution:

> `new Array(1)` or any empty array with positive length

Comment: to easy:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135654/72288

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135667/72664))

Thought I'd try my hand at being a copper! Should be a fun one. I trust you guys but if for some reason it's too hard I'll add hints.

Solution does not require an error, if you somehow error I'll post an update with a try/catch ;)

```javascript
x=>{while(!Number.isInteger(x)||x-2!=x-3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLDsIgEADQfU8xrApNaBNdGty78Q60nRYMMg0fpbGeHX3L99AvHadgtyQ9zVgXVYu6ft7GOuTsnp8jht7Gm0@4YuBFHEeRJ6aKPIvLty4chg62nGCnHCCSy8mSB4MBoRtANM1E/t/YO1p5a7RLOLNW1B8)

Solution:

> The offered solution: 100000000000000000
>
>  Intended solutions (the closest to zero for which this works): Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER+7 or -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER-3
>
>  You just need to go out of safe integers and test a little to get the
>  right floating point inconsistency.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135667/55934)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135681/3527), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135684/12012) - both unintended) ([Intended Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135685/12012))

```javascript
x=>{while(!(x&&x==false));}
```

> The other cracks were genius, but the intended crack `[]` or `new Array()`. Empty array in JavaScript is truthy, but `==` false.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66PCMzJ1VDUaNCTa3C1jYtMac4VVPTuvZ/moaSR6aikuZ/AA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135681/3527)

Comment: @w0lf intended solution doesn't involve using any custom objects, but nice job on that :)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135684/12012)

Comment: @Dennis that's genius 0.o but not what I had in mind either

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135685/12012)

Comment: @Dennis yup that's it.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 143 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135772/21194))

```
try:x=int(input())
except:x=0
p=c=n=0
while x:
 b=x&511
 while (p|c|n)&b or b&(b-1):0
 p|=b;c|=b;n|=b;x>>=12;p>>=1;n*=2
while (x+1)/(c-511)<1:0
```

Not enough math-y ones, which makes sense but is kind'a sad. This one isn't particularly competitive, but it's different to most.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEADvecV6KYlSbCpeUrf/8GjC0hZ0E2KKKfTvsUUvMzCHCUsaPV9KSXExGSdOcuIwJ6mUoOwopK02IqBD3vwZpydBNgIs5uqqtYBfkmF1K6vKgo9gK2lrrUwjIKxoO7eDd@S@R912YVfHR2z/R5lPWp2lq7elumnTlHL3c4RHHOYXcYLB0xtGinT4Ag)

Comment: Bonus points for the provably smallest answer.

Comment: Really nice challenge! [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135772/3527).

Comment: @w0lf Nice work yourself :).

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation of how I arrived to this number. Is it true that it's the smallest? I haven't been able to find a smaller one.

Comment: @w0lf Good explanation. Not the smallest.

Comment: I'm not so good with words... :)

Comment: @w0lf To be totally clear, I'm saying your solution is not the smallest, not making a comment on the size of your explanation.

Comment: OK, I found a smaller one: `324518708703458241391526482018336`

Comment: @w0lf Also not the smallest.

Comment: OK, it's `79305685030021641783052861456`. I was stubborn trying to find it by hand, but this time I wrote a program to find the answer.

Comment: @w0lf That looks about right :). Did you notice the similarity to the N queens problem?

Comment: Yes, I did. :) Except these "queens" only attack below and on the sides..

Answer (score 1):

## SmallTalk, 136 bytes (not a concise language‼) [(cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135989/21194)

```
|n p|n:=stdin nextLine asInteger abs. p:=2 raisedTo:n.[(p printString:3)sorted=(p+p printString:3)sorted and:[n\\5=1]]whileFalse:[nil]
```

Not a **TIO** language, but [GNU SmallTalk](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/) is easily available.

Edited so that the program halts quickly on [CodingGround](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php). The solution is now *really* easy!

Code reads the input from the console.

> The intent with the original code using `n\\239=0` was for the robber to discover the pattern of the numbers without including a modulus criterion: `5 27 40 92 138 929 1086 ...`, searching for `"5 27 40 92 138 929 1086"` in Google brings up one match providing five more terms. The last term is divisible by `239`. Anyway, this term is too large to validate in under 30 seconds in any version of SmallTalk. So I had to pick the largest term which could finish fast enough, which was `1086`. Even the next term `352664` in the sequence after `1086` takes more than an hour to validate in SmallTalk!

Comment: Help plz? Does the answer work on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php? For bonus niceness, does it halt within ~60s?

Comment: @Veedrac - I noticed now the rules say it must halt in < 30 seconds. Have changed the code, it's now *much* easier!

Comment: "really easy". Why do I not trust you... :P

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135989/21194) I should have more faith! A shame you had to make it easier; I've not given up on the original though.

Comment: @Veedrac - Good luck! Hint: remove the modulus check, put in an incrementing loop and see what numbers come out. Don't look at the spolier!

Comment: [Well I've found my new wallpaper.](https://i.imgur.com/UAOdMtK.png)

Comment: I think it might be 30490425, but I'm entirely unable to test it right now.

Comment: Correct for the original challenge. Given `352664` takes about 2½ hours to validate, that term might take 10 months! O(n²) time.

Comment: (*reads spoiler*) Ah, that's what you meant when you said to remove the modulus check. I just brute-forced it!

Comment: Coincidentally 2½ hours is about as long as it took to brute-force :P.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 47 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135706#135706)

```
p->{for(;p==null||p.isEmpty()||!p.isEmpty(););}
```

This is a lambda of type `Consumer<List>`. Basically, it will run as long as the list is null, empty, or non-empty... The answer to this one is pretty simple, I'll try and come up with a truly difficult one for my next answer :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BbsIwEETv/orlliDhfIAbLogbPfWIOLjG0A2OvbLXSIjk21NHBYTUuaxmZvdtp696Fcj67niZsKcQGbqSyczo5A4TK/EvPmVvGIOXm@BT7m1UQlD@dmjAOJ0SfGr0cBcCih5FYs1lXAMeoS919cUR/Xl/AB3PqS7b8NAT@jF/X4MpFlqYaLW@n0KsFLWtz84NA0lM2574VtXDsHhzqlbj9MSpF3gmSW2MJa5mAjRLuIUcAT1lhh8bLSyb@u9gFGKcfgE) (Note, you will have to edit in the input in the function call in the footer)

Just FYI, the intended solution terminates in ~3 seconds (including compilation), so it should be crackable on TIO.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135706/21194)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135705)

```javascript
x=>{while(!(Array.isArray(x)&&x==",,,"));}
```

> An empty array of length 4 (`new Array(4)`), when coerced into a string with `==`, becomes `,,,`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66PCMzJ1VDUcOxqCixUi@zGExrVGiqqVXY2irp6OgoaWpa1/5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI04CK/wcA)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135705)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 44 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135756/21194) and [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135757/62252))

```
f=function(x)while(1)if(length(x))grep(x,'')
```

> This halts if `grep(x,'')` receives invalid regex, which was the intended solution. Also fails when given a function as input.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135756/21194)

Comment: [Also cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135757/62252)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 63 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135800/21194))

```
f=function(x){set.seed(4);try(eval(x));x=rpois(1,1);while(x){}}
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135800/21194)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 60 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135851/59530)

```
f=function(x)while(1)tryCatch(eval(x),error=function(e)NULL)
```

> `tryCatch` prevents exiting through errors or any kind, so the only way to exit is to call `quit()` or `q()`.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135851/21194)

Comment: [Also Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135853/18915)

Comment: @Rift oh damn, I thought I tested that, but I forgot the `expression`.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam you should not have included `eval`

Comment: @Rift Hmm, an earlier iteration had `x()` instead. However, that doesn't immediately terminate with `q`, but rather prompts for saving workspace and yadda yadda.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam `eval(q())` and `q()` both ask for saving workspace. I guess `q("no")` would be better.

Comment: @rift which needs Eval to work :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.5, 69 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135844/59530)

```
def f(x):
 y=str(x)
 while not(x and(y[-1]+y[:-1])==str(2*x)):a=1
```

There is a solution that is an integer.

Cracked by isaacg (in 11 min) and Jarko Dubbeldam.

Comment: 105263157894736842

Comment: @isaacg while true, can you make a post on the robbers thread that I can link to?

Comment: This seems to work for more than one solution: `210526315789473684`, `421052631578947368` and more

Comment: I added these solutions to a post on the robbers thread and edited the link.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++](https://isocpp.org/) ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)/[MSVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/)), 63 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135944/967) ([fixed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136043/967))

```cpp
template<class T,T=T()>T f(T t){for(auto a=0ll;!a;(T&)a=t={});}
```

Tested on Linux and Windows. To compile with MSVC, use `#pragma warning(default:4716)`.

> Veedrac spotted that by supplying template parameters it's possible to make `T` a reference type, allowing a class type with user-defined constructor. Fixed in the [newer version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136043/967) by disallowing reference types using `*`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxLCsMgEIDhfU8xSaEotNB11GxyBS8wjKZIfREnq5Cz28fy54Ofan28iHpnn2pE9poitgb2bo0VcrawCgssj7VsAncugOYZoxpQCXuTaNgcp1Rnv4ZMcXcedCiNN49pvoTMkDBkIeH4flgqaOymicrOoDWMy4b09m4Yf/Unn11UcPYP)

Comment: Are we allowed to specify the template parameters to `f` when calling it?

Comment: @Veedrac yes, certainly - as long as it compiles (and doesn't crash *before* entering `f`) any parameters are fine.

Comment: ... although my intended solution doesn't require any template arguments to be supplied.

Comment: Ugh, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135944/21194) I guess.

Comment: @Veedrac I didn't intend to allow reference types! Fixed to disallow those - want to have another go?

Comment: To be consistent with other unexpectedly-cracked challenges, you should probably post the update in a new submission.

Comment: @Veedrac thanks, I'll do that. Might have to wait till tomorrow as I'm on mobile here.

Comment: @Veedrac new version is at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136043/967

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Browser), 62 bytes (cracked)

```js
x=>{while(!x||(!(x[Symbol.toPrimitive]=()=>true))||+x||true);}
```

Solution should work in modern browsers on all pages.
Is possible without `.toPrimitive` (or similar) trickery ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136264/42091)) - is also possible *with* `.toPrimitive` (or similar) trickery ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135992/72685)) :P

Intended solutions:

W/o `.toPrimitive` or similar:

> ```
> let i = document.createElement("iframe");
> i.src="https://google.com";
> i.onload=a=>f(i.contentWindow);
> document.body.appendChild(i);
> ```

[W/ `.toPrimitive`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135992#135992)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135992/21194)

Comment: @Veedrac Nice! Now we just need the solution without `.toPrimitive`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'd say that counts ;)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136264/42091)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136001/20080)

```
J<w17#.x$eval(J)$0
```

[Code](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38um3NBcWa9CJbUsMUfDS1PF4P9/AA)

You must give an input - it'll just hang waiting for input and not terminate otherwise.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136001/21194)

Comment: @Veedrac Darn - not what I intended. I'll have to try again.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 145 bytes (Version 2.0)

```
f=function(x)if(tryCatch(x=="length"|x=="q"|x==".Internal"|x=="quit"|x=="is.list"|!getAnywhere(x)$objs[[1]](list(0)),error=function(e)1))repeat{}
```

## R, 145 bytes [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136214/62252)

```
f=function(x)if(tryCatch(x=="length"|x=="q"|x==".Internal"|x=="quit"|x=="is.list"|!getAnywhere(x)$objs[[1]](list(1)),error=function(e)1))repeat{}
```

Modification of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135857/59530). Creating your own version of `is.list` won't work this time :)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136214/62252)

Comment: @Gregor nicely done! See if you can crack this!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 25 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136148/65836)

```javascript
x=>{for(;!(x&&"."**x););}
```

Intended solution:

> `"0"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q46Lb9Iw1pRo0JNTUlPSUurQtNa07r2f5pGdUlqcYlVSVFpaq3mfwA)

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136148/58974).

Comment: @Shaggy yup, there's a couple other (equivalent) solutions

Comment: Yeah, I also just found that `String.prototype` works too.

Comment: @Shaggy why the flippity flappity does `String.prototype == false`

Comment: Because JS is weird?! `Array.prototype` also works but, strangely, `Object.prototype` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js >= 6.0)](https://tio.run/##jZFNT8MwDIb/Srm0jlQiOFeZxAFOHJB24IAQCpnLAllSEq9dVe23j6RlHxogcXMc@31sv@@ylUF53dCldQvc1WIHL2I2GKSsFUHMsJUGAqvGDAqPn2vtEQps0VIoGL9Nwe1KE6HnjXfkqG@wQm50ILTog7DYZQ/ebXo4yZaDbBrTA5WqlGzQNcinq2chCtxoKphHWnv79FxNQUZ8Kk/F2y2L@h5XrsUbY@5/Bf38/hcxU38R0wG6EfGI8mOOBKwaYRHVOiVfDZ4McPZzxk5aXpwSqo7LxQLGE256th/CJ/Koda5dDsrZQH6tKKrK0k6qzVhHwDk/iDYHuWa/iBHJ5W6pDcI1q7ZVxCoMgTsL0z1Kc@jSsZR8ny520fGlDKBZnutMR760Cl2d3a2tIu1snif3Y0JfiKL@ThZ53sKcvLZvsZMJIXRshxQcs8N@gsm4vWvHabZoAg4GohlKklqCY9Mr7gRsV6eV2e4L), <s>708</s> 694 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136735/42091)

```
(_=>{let v=s=>eval(s);{let e=require('events').EventEmitter.prototype;e.listeners=new Proxy(e.listeners,{apply(t,c,a){if(a[0]=='exit')return[];return t.apply(c,a)}});e.removeAllListeners=new Proxy(e.removeAllListeners,{apply(t,c,a){if(a[0]=='exit')return c;return t.apply(c,a)}});let w=new WeakSet();Proxy.revocable=new Proxy(Proxy.revocable,{apply(t,c,a){let r=t.apply(c,a);w.add(r.proxy);return r}});Proxy=new Proxy(Proxy,{construct(t,a,n){let p=new t(...a);w.add(p);return p}});let l=_=>{while(1);};process.on('exit',l);return i=>{try{if(!w.has(i)&&i instanceof Function&&typeof i!='function'&&v(String(i))===i&&i()===String(i)){process.removeListener('exit',l)}else{l()}}catch(o){l()}}}})()
```

Don't let the size deter you. Most of it is to just prevent you from trying to get past my intended solution doing the "obvious" stuff.

I hope this isn't more simple than I thought it was, but I assure you it's possible. I've tested on my computer and also on TIO to make sure it wasn't dependent on a particular version of Node.js or something.

This is a function submission, so assign it to a variable and call it with your intended input.

And maybe I'm not supposed to enforce this, but the input for the intended crack doesn't require any pre-processing, it can just be solved by doing this:

```
f=[708 bytes...]
f([your input])
```

#### Comment on @hvd's crack

I will reveal one part of the intended solution, since it is no longer relevant, and hvd's approach was much more elegant anyway.

```
Object.create((class extends Function{toString(){process.kill(0)}}).prototype)
```

would have been how I would have written that particular crack, since I had not thought of using `__proto__` in an object literal, so kudos.

#### Edit 1

Sorry, forgot to invoke the IIFE, otherwise *any* input would have worked :P

#### Edit 2

This doesn't change the challenge at all, it just addresses the [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/will-it-halt-cops/136145#comment333467_136294) claiming

> Halts with error, `let` not supported without strict mode. If fix `t(...a)` is unexpected token.

by explicitly defining the accepted range of versions in which these errors don't occur, making the challenge valid.

#### Edit 3

By moving the call to `process.on('exit',l)` from the function call into the IIFE scope, I prevented the stupid input of

```
process.on=()=>process.exit()
```

from working. An interesting side-effect of this change is that *not* calling the function causes the program to hang as well!

However, the intended solution is still the same, and the rest of the changes were only for golfing purposes. Carry on!

<sub>(And the timer for marking "safe" has been reset as of this edit because it is major)</sub>

Comment: [A slightly easier to work with TIO](https://goo.gl/fThxNU)

Comment: @Birjolaxew Heh, I see you've discovered the basics of my challenge, but the question remains if you can find the answer~ (at least I hope I've narrowed it to one)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I got stuck on implementing `[[Call]]` without `typeof i === "function"` (since that's how the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator) defines `typeof === "function"` :P)

Comment: @Birjolaxew then how do you explain `var call = Function.call; console.log(typeof call); call()`? I'm not saying it's entirely useful here, but I'm just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: @Birjolaxew if I just found an unintended solution, should I update the challenge or wait for someone to crack it before updating?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'd probably just update the challenge, and make an edit mentioning the change. It'd be another thing if it had already been cracked.

Comment: @Birjolaxew done

Comment: By the way, your code (`var call = Function.call; console.log(typeof call);`) [gives `"function"`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LLFIITkxJ0fBVsGtNC@5JDM/Tw/Et1ZIzs8rzs9J1cvJT9coqSxIzU8DK9S0BlMamtb//wMA), exactly as expected.

Comment: @Birjolaxew oh I know, but my point was it doesn't implement [[Call]] on its own, so that definition doesn't apply to everything.

Comment: But it does implement `[[Call]]` through its prototype, just like all other functions.

`.call` also is not the same as the internal `[[Call]]`.

Comment: "And maybe I'm not supposed to enforce this" -- you should enforce this, to prevent something like `function WeakSet(){process.exit()}` from being used in an answer. :)

Comment: @hvd that wouldn't work since the IIFE is already assumed to be invoked

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It does work, because the IIFE sees the `WeakSet` function definition even if it appears later in the code at a point where execution hasn't reached yet.

Comment: @hvd ah right, hoisting, fair point...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136735/16385), but probably not the way you were going for.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 81 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136557/62501)

```
try:x,y,z=raw_input().split(',');setattr(__import__(x),y,z)
except:0
while True:0
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136557/48931)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 517 bytes (safe)

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Map;
class M{
	public static void main(String[] cm){
		try{
			Class<?>cl=Class.forName(cm[0]);
			Constructor<?>ct=cl.getConstructor();
			Map<Integer,Integer>m=(Map)ct.newInstance();
			String str="Hello World";
			for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
				char c=str.charAt(i);
				int cc=m.getOrDefault(new Integer(c),new Integer(0));
				cc++;
				m.put(new Integer(c),new Integer(cc));
			}
			while(m.size()<9);
		}catch(Throwable t){
			while(true);
		}
	}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZA9b4MwEIZn@BVWJiNSK2sFTlWlQzOkHVqpQ5TBuTjg1B/IHInaKr@d2oDUTJUQd/ie13qOkziLO9dIezp89r0yjfNITuGQaWEr5uVRS0C2crZF3wE6X6S3VIdKs41oihS0aFuy@UmTpttrBaRFgaGcnToQI5Slb@iVrbY7AiYLWIL@K5ZkFZPlwxI0H1p2dP5FGEnBbBe7rBiYP4FIIgfNKok3x3QEg0u5tigr6edTXRpOw3EW9rDysg4JYUFO/CgVZD2fPUutHflwXh9mwzCIEKosEsUXhSoDxLS0FdYhrPJ82CJJoBaeAI/T2D4iVePdSYwCcBNVX/2TPIpOIw0SZFKjkM1vPxfZlATI87EzrOn@zQBMoWt8XWqlJTWsVd9hxfJ@GF1BINT0vfbuIvZaEhzVRzj8QDliaXiufd//Ag)

Input via the command line arguments.

A little long and verbose, but hey, it's got reflection!

## Golfed a little more, 432 bytes

(Thanks to Stephen!)

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;import java.util.Map;class M{public static void main(String[]a){try{Class<?>l=Class.forName(a[0]);Constructor<?>t=l.getConstructor();Map<Integer,Integer>m=(Map)t.newInstance();String s="Hello World";for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){char c=s.charAt(i);int C=m.getOrDefault(new Integer(c),new Integer(0));C++;m.put(new Integer(c),new Integer(C));}while(m.size()<9);}catch(Throwable t){while(true);}}}
```

Halting input:

> java.util.IdentityHashMap

Comment: It seems very long to me for a code-golf.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I know this is [tag:cops-and-robbers], but you can get 432 bytes by golfing variable names and whitespace: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZCxTsMwEIZfxepkK8XqipIUoTDQoTCAxFB1ONxr4uLYkX1pBVGfPVxph0xMd/ffJ31nH@AId6FDf9h9jaNtuxBJHDjUDnytI@4dGtJV8IlibyjEfAr1ZJ1eQ5cbBymJ9dD1n84akQiIyzHYnWjBevlG0fp6swU1UPweqgtePCxd@dfpfYgv0KKEzWKr8omNGSqdrpEmoVQ5O4uVJ6wxzm912ZaSY0Xa42nFMHiDjF7VIpWzZ3QuiI8Q3W6Ws1JaT8KWi9wWSTv0NTXM2yxTg2kgClMmfWkeSVrOGa7K9nLLa3zCPfSOJKvEzS@Nmk/HheKXZFne6q7/F6wYPJ8a61C2OtkfPrq458gAmUa@NzGc4NOhIDVcKf4G5P35PI7jLw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Toto It's indeed not the golfiest thing in the world, but it does use some rather unusual features of Java.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks a lot! Had to leave the computer for a while and wanted to post the thing before I went. :)
(Double comment because I can't mention two people at once)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
x=>{try{while(typeof x!='string'||!x.match`^[()[\\]!+]{4321}$`|eval(x)!='☆');}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66pKiyujwjMydVo6SyIDU/TaFC0Va9uKQoMy9dvaZGsUIvN7EkOSMhLlpDMzomJlZRO7baxNjIsFYloSa1LDFHo0ITqP7RjDZ1TevaZJBSjVTN6rT8Ig1ra6BI7f//AA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/188426#188426)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64, 5 bytes assembled, SAFE

```
halty:
  verr si
  jnz $
  ret
```

This is a pretty simple "warm up" I came up with. Shouldn't be difficult at all to crack. Takes input in rsi.

Why did this win.

> The solution is simple, at least on my computer. rsi == 32 will cause it to halt. In fact, it has multiple possible inputs that will cause it to halt. verr checks if the segment supplied in %r can be read. IF it can't, the zero flag is set, and the function returns.

Comment: I think a `0` as input would halt this one (line 3 is `jump if not zero`). I don't have a way to run it and check though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplefunge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/simplefunge), 1028 bytes, safe

```
0ooooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOoo9ooOOoOOoOOoOoOOoOoOoOOOOoOoOoOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooIOoOoOoOoOOoOOooOOo-ov
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooooo
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooooO
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooooo
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooooO
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooooo
ooooOOOOooOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo@oooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooH
```

> The answer is the tab character

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJTSvNS0/9/98gHyvwRwL5@ZYgARiCEmAl@QgmsQDJEk@EfhACYd38Mi6Y/ciWErSDkCdI04omNfic5D8aSiMrlBxo5yaP//8TAQ)

Comment: Um, this halts with *no* input

Comment: Oh, okay. Does that count?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 226 bytes, [cracked by hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226042/94066) (intended solution)

Not really golfed.

```py
def f(x):
    to_be = x == x
    while to_be or not to_be:
        pass
    while True:
        pass
    while 1:
        pass
    i = input()
    s = '!@#$%^&*()_+'
    if all(c in i for c in s):
        exec(i[0xf91ea8222d])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo0LTiksBCEry45NSFWwVKhRsgQRYqDwjMycVKpFfpJCXXwLhQDSAQEFicTGS0pCiUtyShlhkMoEWZuYVlJZoaIL5xUC@uqKDsopqnJqWhma8tjpEWZpCYk6ORjJQLVBLGtAtYGaxJsLI1IrUZI3MaIOKNEvD1EQLIyOjlFhNLi6uNA1DI2MTUzPN//8B) Super simple, but I just wanted to make that reference. Also, since this is a function, you can't pass input to STDIN.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this challenge. I don't suppose something like [this](https://tio.run/##dU/LCsIwELznK1Z8NFEPWi8qFOw/eBMNtU1oIDS1STF@fdy2ggq6h2VnZ2Yf9cOVptqEUAgJknq2J4DhDL8KSMBDgqlv3UulxYswDVTGDWAwdFFn1n5Ij037n1z/YBQuVFXdOsp6bBFHo8N4Mr3M5pTxRTTIJGRa0xy1aJF4S19a9h4pvMipOq283K1Fto3juDgzQkiucRekg7D7mHNx45xaoeUS/NcE1Z1BJE0pYyE8AQ) would be allowed?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino That is exactly it! Go ahead and post that on the robbers' thread

Comment: There's also [this](https://tio.run/##dY9NDoIwEIXXcIox/rXqQnGjJCTewI07ow3CNNQ0FGmNeHoci0YXOoumr997M9Pq7gpTLts2RwmSNTwOgcoZcUJIoIGEDv90K5TGFzA1lMZ1ogs8q0qt/bLu6ut/uPhBFA1UZXV1jHttSY97m/5geBxNGBfTcWeTkGrNMvJSRNIu/mr5pyU2mDG1nzdyvcB0FUVRfuBtpmkSbE/nOAye3xVClcoJwSxqSekg8Ku8IV5eaAbGFVh7R50qi2EoGbVhnLcP)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yeah that works too

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226042/68942). I thought it would be crackable with inputting `NaN` at first until I took a closer look :P

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 125 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226115/16484)

```js
f=y=>{while(x=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty)try{1+(x.call(y||{},'toString')||x.call(y||{},'valueOf')?1:y)}catch(y){return}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VclLDsIgEADQu7gpRG3SrUn1CDXxBIiDbUMYMp1@JsDZce3bvtlsZrE0Rb4G/ECtrpf@nvZx8qCOfnjPYLmNhIwsEdrRLMMenoQRiEUzSerO6mit8V5JzqlcGsYX0xS@jc75fzbjVxhcox/dTXSxhu2oRCcCXimUUp06OcSTrj8)

Solution:

> We want an input that will throw when cast to a string or a primitive value, the easiest such input is `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: So, we're meant to throw an error with a non-object...

Comment: @Ausername The first iteration I wrote of this was easier, but in my opinion a bit too easy, I tried to make it an interesting challenge. :)

Comment: Researching Javascript oddities...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/226115#226115), although I don't think you intended this.

Comment: @Ausername Nice! Indeed not what I had in mind, but still a very creative take on it. If you're interested in the original solution, I've added it in a spoiler.

Comment: Thanks, and nice puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 123 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135472/65836)

```javascript
x=>y=>{try{console.assert(/3$/.test(x));n=y*321;c=x===n.toString().replace(/2$/,3)&&+x===n;if(c)return;}catch(e){}for(;;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpdCoMwDADgy4gk@2lRH0u8xE5Quugc0kqaDYt49g72PX9v//U5yLLpPaYn15nqTmOh8VApR0gxp5WNz5lFwQ6NNcpZYUd0kcpl6DsXaCeiaDQ9VJY4AxrhbfWBwfaNvQ3Yttd/ccsEAYX1I9GdwWt4AeNxTknAOXRnnaFD6LH@AA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135472/61875)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 144 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135475#135475))([Cracked 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135539#135539)) ([Intended Crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136587#136587))

This should be an easy one. Compile without optimizations.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
char*a="abcd";char b[256];fun(){char c['\b'];char*d=a;fgets(c,'\f',stdin);snprintf(b,sizeof(c),c,d);}
main(){while(1)fun();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxNDoIwGEXROasgOGhLilETmVTcggsABu3XH5pgMbTEROPWrbbDd19yoDEAMe6sg3mTqrz4IO2yn64FTHyteVdxAbJiaZWiP53bkenNYfLOBXo0CDTmu5YdZ9qo4DFQNGhEk@UI8@6xWhc0FtTbl1o0BkKBSsI@xZ3bhD0nOyt8JJn@5xi/oGdufGxuhx8)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135475#135475)

Comment: [Cracked the intended way?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135539/63348)

Comment: [Cracked, third times a charm at getting the intended solution?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136587#136587)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes ([Cracked, not intended solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135510/10894))

```javascript
x=>{while(x.constructor);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q66PCMzJ1WjQi85P6@4pKg0uSS/SNO69n@ahoHmfwA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135510/10894)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188506)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript in Firefox console (on blank.org), 7,987 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135531/31957))

Not contending to win, but this should be fun.

```js
f=B=>{eval("if(typeof B!='number')B=0;if(typeof Β!='number')Β=0;".repeat(4).repeat(2));while(B<=0||B==1||B==2||B==3||B==4||B==5||B==6||B==7||B==8||B==9||B==10||B==11||B==12||B==13||B==14||B==15||B==16||B==17||B==18||B==19||B==20||B==21||B==22||B==23||B==24||B==25||B==26||B==27||B==28||B==29||B==30||B==31||B==32||B==33||B==34||B==35||B==36||B==37||B==38||B==39||B==40||B==41||B==42||B==43||B==44||B==45||B==46||B==47||B==48||B==49||B==50||B==51||B==52||B==53||B==54||B==55||B==56||B==57||B==58||B==59||B==60||B==61||B==62||B==63||B==64||B==65||B==66||B==67||B==68||B==69||B==70||B==71||B==72||B==73||B==74||B==75||B==76||B==77||B==78||B==79||B==80||B==81||B==82||B==83||B==84||B==85||B==86||B==87||B==88||B==89||B==90||B==91||B==92||B==93||B==94||B==95||B==96||B==97||B==98||B==99||B==100||B==101||B==102||B==103||B==104||B==105||B==106||B==107||B==108||B==109||B==110||B==111||B==112||B==113||B==114||B==115||B==116||B==117||B==118||B==119||B==120||B==121||B==122||B==123||B==124||B==125||B==126||B==127||B==128||B==129||B==130||B==131||B==132||B==133||B==134||B==135||B==136||B==137||B==138||B==139||B==140||B==141||B==142||B==143||B==144||B==145||B==146||B==147||B==148||B==149||B==150||B==151||B==152||B==153||B==154||B==155||B==156||B==157||B==158||B==159||B==160||B==161||B==162||B==163||B==164||B==165||B==166||B==167||B==168||B==169||B==170||B==171||B==172||B==173||B==174||B==175||B==176||B==177||B==178||B==179||B==180||B==181||B==182||B==183||B==184||B==185||B==186||B==187||B==188||B==189||B==190||B==191||B==192||B==193||B==194||B==195||B==196||B==197||B==198||B==199||B==200||B==201||B==202||B==203||B==204||B==205||B==206||B==207||B==208||B==209||B==210||B==211||B==212||B==213||B==214||B==215||B==216||B==217||B==218||B==219||B==220||B==221||B==222||B==223||B==224||B==225||B==226||B==227||B==228||B==229||B==230||B==231||B==232||B==233||B==234||B==235||B==236||B==237||B==238||B==239||B==240||B==241||B==242||B==243||B==244||B==245||B==246||B==247||B==248||B==249||B==250||B==251||B==252||B==253||B==254||B==255||B==256||B==257||B==258||B==259||B==260||B==261||B==262||B==263||B==264||B==265||B==266||B==267||B==268||B==269||B==270||B==271||B==272||B==273||B==274||B==275||B==276||B==277||B==278||B==279||B==280||B==281||B==282||B==283||B==284||B==285||B==286||B==287||B==288||B==289||B==290||B==291||B==292||B==293||B==294||B==295||B==296||B==297||B==298||B==299||B==300||B==301||B==302||B==303||B==304||B==305||B==306||B==307||B==308||B==309||B==310||B==311||B==312||B==313||B==314||B==315||B==316||B==317||B==318||B==319||B==320||B==321||B==322||B==323||B==324||B==325||B==326||B==327||B==328||B==329||B==330||B==331||B==332||B==333||B==334||B==335||B==336||B==337||B==338||B==339||B==340||B==341||B==342||B==343||B==344||B==345||B==346||B==347||B==348||B==349||B==350||B==351||B==352||B==353||B==354||B==355||B==356||B==357||B==358||B==359||B==360||B==361||B==362||B==363||B==364||B==365||B==366||B==367||B==368||B==369||B==370||B==371||B==372||B==373||B==374||B==375||B==376||B==377||B==378||B==379||B==380||B==381||B==382||B==383||B==384||B==385||B==386||B==387||B==388||B==389||B==390||B==391||B==392||B==393||B==394||B==395||B==396||B==397||B==398||B==399||B==400||B==401||B==402||B==403||B==404||B==405||B==406||B==407||B==408||B==409||B==410||B==411||B==412||B==413||B==414||B==415||B==416||B==417||B==418||B==419||B==420||B==421||B==422||B==423||B==424||B==425||B==426||B==427||B==428||B==429||B==430||B==431||B==432||B==433||B==434||B==435||B==436||B==437||B==438||B==439||B==440||B==441||B==442||B==443||B==444||B==445||B==446||B==447||B==448||B==449||B==450||B==451||B==452||B==453||B==454||B==455||B==456||B==457||B==458||B==459||B==460||B==461||B==462||B==463||B==464||B==465||B==466||B==467||B==468||B==469||B==470||B==471||B==472||B==473||B==474||B==475||B==476||B==477||B==478||B==479||B==480||B==481||B==482||B==483||B==484||B==485||B==486||B==487||B==488||B==489||B==490||B==491||B==492||B==493||B==494||B==495||B==496||B==497||B==498||B==499||B==500||B==501||B==502||B==503||B==504||B==505||B==506||B==507||B==508||B==509||B==510||B==511||B==512||B==513||B==514||B==515||B==516||B==517||B==518||B==519||B==520||B==521||B==522||B==523||B==524||B==525||B==526||B==527||B==528||B==529||B==530||B==531||B==532||B==533||B==534||B==535||B==536||B==537||B==538||B==539||B==540||B==541||B==542||B==543||B==544||B==545||B==546||B==547||B==548||B==549||B==550||B==551||B==552||B==553||B==554||B==555||B==556||B==557||B==558||B==559||B==560||B==561||B==562||B==563||B==564||B==565||Β==566||B==567||B==568||B==569||B==570||B==571||B==572||B==573||B==574||B==575||B==576||B==577||B==578||B==579||B==580||B==581||B==582||B==583||B==584||B==585||B==586||B==587||B==588||B==589||B==590||B==591||B==592||B==593||B==594||B==595||B==596||B==597||B==598||B==599||B==600||B==601||B==602||B==603||B==604||B==605||B==606||B==607||B==608||B==609||B==610||B==611||B==612||B==613||B==614||B==615||B==616||B==617||B==618||B==619||B==620||B==621||B==622||B==623||B==624||B==625||B==626||B==627||B==628||B==629||B==630||B==631||B==632||B==633||B==634||B==635||B==636||B==637||B==638||B==639||B==640||B==641||B==642||B==643||B==644||B==645||B==646||B==647||B==648||B==649||B==650||B==651||B==652||B==653||B==654||B==655||B==656||B==657||B==658||B==659||B==660||B==661||B==662||B==663||B==664||B==665||B==666||B==667||B==668||B==669||B==670||B==671||B==672||B==673||B==674||B==675||B==676||B==677||B==678||B==679||B==680||B==681||B==682||B==683||B==684||B==685||B==686||B==687||B==688||B==689||B==690||B==691||B==692||B==693||B==694||B==695||B==696||B==697||B==698||B==699||B==700||B==701||B==702||B==703||B==704||B==705||B==706||B==707||B==708||B==709||B==710||B==711||B==712||B==713||B==714||B==715||B==716||B==717||B==718||B==719||B==720||B==721||B==722||B==723||B==724||B==725||B==726||B==727||B==728||B==729||B==730||B==731||B==732||B==733||B==734||B==735||B==736||B==737||B==738||B==739||B==740||B==741||B==742||B==743||B==744||B==745||B==746||B==747||B==748||B==749||B==750||B==751||B==752||B==753||B==754||B==755||B==756||B==757||B==758||B==759||B==760||B==761||B==762||B==763||B==764||B==765||B==766||B==767||B==768||B==769||B==770||B==771||B==772||B==773||B==774||B==775||B==776||B==777||B==778||B==779||B==780||B==781||B==782||B==783||B==784||B==785||B==786||B==787||B==788||B==789||B==790||B==791||B==792||B==793||B==794||B==795||B==796||B==797||B==798||B==799||B==800||B==801||B==802||B==803||B==804||B==805||B==806||B==807||B==808||B==809||B==810||B==811||B==812||B==813||B==814||B==815||B==816||B==817||B==818||B==819||B==820||B==821||B==822||B==823||B==824||B==825||B==826||B==827||B==828||B==829||B==830||B==831||B==832||B==833||B==834||B==835||B==836||B==837||B==838||B==839||B==840||B==841||B==842||B==843||B==844||B==845||B==846||B==847||B==848||B==849||B==850||B==851||B==852||B==853||B==854||B==855||B==856||B==857||B==858||B==859||B==860||B==861||B==862||B==863||B==864||B==865||B==866||B==867||B==868||B==869||B==870||B==871||B==872||B==873||B==874||B==875||B==876||B==877||B==878||B==879||B==880||B==881||B==882||B==883||B==884||B==885||B==886||B==887||B==888||B==889||B==890||B==891||B==892||B==893||B==894||B==895||B==896||B==897||B==898||B==899||B==900||B==901||B==902||B==903||B==904||B==905||B==906||B==907||B==908||B==909||B==910||B==911||B==912||B==913||B==914||B==915||B==916||B==917||B==918||B==919||B==920||B==921||B==922||B==923||B==924||B==925||B==926||B==927||B==928||B==929||B==930||B==931||B==932||B==933||B==934||B==935||B==936||B==937||B==938||B==939||B==940||B==941||B==942||B==943||B==944||B==945||B==946||B==947||B==948||B==949||B==950||B==951||B==952||B==953||B==954||B==955||B==956||B==957||B==958||B==959||B==960||B==961||B==962||B==963||B==964||B==965||B==966||B==967||B==968||B==969||B==970||B==971||B==972||B==973||B==974||B==975||B==976||B==977||B==978||B==979||B==980||B==981||B==982||B==983||B==984||B==985||B==986||B==987||B==988||B==989||B==990||B==991||B==992||B==993||B==994||B==995||B==996||B==997||B==998||B>=999);}
```

There's another crack out there, waiting to be found... Cracks:

> - NaN (unintended)
>  - decimals

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135531/59682)

Comment: Also [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135533/59682) by [Haumed Rahmani](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72664/haumed-rahmani) (who doesn't have enough reputation to comment here).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135569/38941)

```
x=>{try{for(;x.x||!x.x;);}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38X5ZYpFBUmmf7v8LWrrqkqLI6Lb9Iw7pCr6KmRhFIWmta1yYnliRnaKRqQqRAIrX/gVo0lDJyc3P19PQUijNzcioVvIA2BINtUNL8DwA)

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135569/44718

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 34 bytes, Possibly cracked

```
> #;de+294&:0\`#;_3*+*\-\0pqk$#q_
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get this to halt in <s>TIO or</s> [CCBI](https://github.com/Deewiant/CCBI), but it works in [BefungeSharp](https://github.com/tngreene/BefungeSharp). <s>(If you can find a way to make it halt on TIO, mock me mercilessly)</s> @ovs figured one out which depends on the fact that...

> TIO does not implement the `=` instruction, making it behave like `r`. When the reversed IP encounters `p`, it deletes `>` from the program start, allowing the IP to run backwards to `q_`. This could be fixed by adding a leading space to the program (and replacing `de+` with `ee+`).

To run the program:

1. Save the above code to a file somewhere
2. Run BefungeSharp (it will probably work under Wine)
3. Press `2` (open file) and find the file you saved from before
4. (Press any key to continue)
5. Press a key from F2 to F5 to run (F2 = slow, F5 = fast)
6. Hit F12 to stop execution, and alt-R to reload

The program won't halt on TIO or CCBI. (I blame ambiguous Funge-98 specs.) Inputs which crash BefungeSharp do not count.

`&` asks for a number, so input a number. To save you some time, the program ignores negatives.

Comment: [It halts for 1 on TIO](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/305B2TolVdvI0kTNyiAmQdk63lhLWytGN8agoDBbRbkw/v9/QwA), but I don't think this is the intended solution.

Comment: Indeed, it is not, @ovs. Since I can't reproduce that in BefungeSharp, it's very difficult to figure out what's going on. I think that `=` causes the instruction pointer to reverse delta (proper way for an interpreter to handle unimplemented instructions). I hadn't thought of that, but I suppose it's valid!

Comment: Does this have something to do with integer overflow?

Comment: @ppperry Nope. Just pure arithmetic and ASCII

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes (Cracked [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135736/3527) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135814/3527))

```js
x=>{while(!(x&&1+x!==1+x));}
```

> Both cracks were unexpected and I find them very clever (that's why I love this site). The crack I intended was `{valueOf: function(){}}`.

Comment: [Cracked (the lazy way).](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135736/21194)

Comment: @Veedrac Great job! Although not exactly what I had in mind. I've added error handling - can you beat [level 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135743/3527)? :)

Comment: [Another Crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135814/44718)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 119 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135694/58826)

```javascript
x=>{try{while(typeof x!="string");x=x.trim();while(!(x.length==6&&x[4]==" "&&eval(x)===undefined));}catch(e){for(;;);}}
```

While cracking this with the usual JavaScript prototype changing and object stuff is probably possible, the intended solution is a regular old string.

> `"void 0"` evaluates to `undefined`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpBCoMwEEDRq2gWYWZRV6WbML1I6SLEiaakicRoI@LZU6HQ3efzXnrVs0luypcQe66WaqH7ntO2f0bnGfI2cbRNaUnMObkwCFSFSnf2G1D9UAul8xyGPBLdpCyP65NINEJKXrWHgkS0hJ6tC9wjqsPobEZg3G1MoNR5jmpimKPnzscBLIi/F4j1Cw)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135694/58826). Is this the intended solution?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 52 bytes ([Cracked again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135736/3527))

```js
x=>{while(1){try{if(x&&1+x!==1+x)break;}catch(e){}}}
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135736/21194)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 134 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136063/38550))

```
f=function(x)if(tryCatch(!is.function(x)|identical(x,q)|identical(x,quit)|identical(x,is.list)|!x(list()),error=function(e)1))repeat{}
```

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135884/53286)

Comment: @MischaBehrend Not the intended solution, and arguably not even a solution, since the quitting happens in the definition of the argument, not while executing the function.

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136063/38550) by @CriminallyVulgar.

Comment: Cracked. I didn't consider that option. Since my intended solution isn't found, I'll make a new version without showing it here.

Answer (score 0):

### BASIC, 8 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135905/61563))

`1input x`

Meets the conditions of the OP completely, other than TIO which was a request not a condition.

Try it.

It'll hang forever (machine stability required) and terminate predictably within << a second of any input. Probably not what the OP meant but perfectly fair. Alls fair in love and golf!

Comment: Hey! Don't give away what the input is. Other people are meant to guess it! (Also, apostrophe.)

Comment: Heheeeee! Shall we tell them? After all, anyone inspecting it can work it out.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135905/55934)

Answer (score 0):

### CPython 3.6, 634 bytes, [Cracked](/a/135901)

Fixed a misplaced `try:` statement that allowed `1/0` and even no input to break things. [Original](/a/135892/43394).

```
try:j=input();__builtins__.__dict__["__import__"]=eval(j);import random,functools,itertools,zlib;exec("@functools.lru_cache(None)\ndef f():i=input();return(all(x is y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest((x for x in sorted(dir(eval(i[::2])))if'_'not in x),sorted{}))\nand all(x is y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest((x for x in sorted(dir(eval(i[1::2])))if'_'not in x),sorted{}))and 8 and zlib.crc32(bytes(i,'ASCII'))==zlib.crc32(bytes(j,'ASCII')))".format(*eval('('+"(tuple(''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')for x in range%s)for x in range%s),),"%(("(random.randint(1,9))",)*2)*2+')')));f()
except:f=bool
while not f():8
```

Comment: Nice try, but [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135901#135901)

Comment: @ppperry That is indeed a valid solution.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 From the question: If a robber cracks your submission, please mark it as cracked and show the halting input (in a > ! spoiler quote). (this will make the included snippet behave correctly)

Comment: @NieDzejkob Oops! I forgot to do that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 67 characters ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136013/12012))

An easy one, though this one is actually worth knowing so I thought I'd throw it in anyway.

```
import shutil,sys
while 1:shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin,sys.stdout)
```

Input goes in `stdin`.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that this will only work with certain locales? If so, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136013/12012).

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I would have specified but I figured a hint wasn't needed on a question this simple.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge 93](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), 13 bytes, [cracked by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136334/42854)

<sup>13 bytes: if you crack me you will get bad luck forever!!! ~Spooky~</sup>

```
~345**-0/#v_@
```

Unfortunately this one's pretty crackable.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136334/64121)

Answer (score 0):

Lua, 107 Bytes, [Cracked](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wrYkP680Nym1SCMzX68oNTFFQ1Mzv0jBSKESp0xmmkJlnEaFqqmmdoVWpXZlnW1FnLGuRoWuoZGBplaFQklGap5CeUZmTqqCoUJKvkJqXgoI//9vyGViAAA)

I hate how verbose lua is - getting inputs takes up almost half the program.

```
x=tonumber(io.read())or 2 y=tonumber(io.read())or 2 if y^(x%5)+x*y+y~=x^3-(x-120)*x then while 1 do end end
```

I tried to account for all trivial solutions - hopefully this works.

Comment: Is this harder than solving an equation? [Cracked](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wrYkP680Nym1SCMzX68oNTFFQ1Mzv0jBSKESp0xmmkJlnEaFqqmmdoVWpXZlnW1FnLGuRoWuoZGBplaFQklGap5CeUZmTqqCoUJKvkJqXgoI//9vyGViAAA).

Comment: Just for fun, [here's](https://pastebin.com/Xm54QtDv) my attempt at golfing the code :)

Comment: @tehtmi Wow! I didn't try hard to golf this one, but I definitely couldn't have done what you did. I'm still on Lua 5.1, can you explain the "..." to me?

Comment: `...` is used for "vararg" functions. E.g. `function myprint(category,...)print("My Print ["..category.."]:",...)end`. If `...` is used at the end of an expression list (arguments or assignment), it is like `arg1, arg2, arg3, -- and so on`. `x,y=...` is like `x,y=arg1,arg2`. When running from the command line, the outer-level of the script is implicitly a function and the command line arguments are passed to it. E.g. `lua my_script.lua arg1 arg2`. The arguments are also in a table called `arg` which also includes the others components of the command line call at `arg[0], arg[-1]`, etc.

Comment: @tehtmi Wow, I knew that, but I never thought of taking input from command line... this really helps one of the programs I'm working on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 19 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136720#136720))

```
while(lambda:1)():0
```

**How to input:**

Write any code *above* this statement, following some simple restrictions against low-hanging fruit:

- The line must be reached, *unconditionally*. A solution must reach this line even in unlikely scenarios.
- No threads or processes may be spawned,
- The solution must run on Python 2 (CPython and PyPy) *and* Python 3 (CPython).

[Try it online (Python 2, CPython).](https://tio.run/##NYyxDsIwDET3fsWJLu1SAWNnPgGJOaUWiZTaUZoo6tcHpwgP9ul898KRrPC91h6v6BLhkBzxlpVgKdLc6fR4CFgSypkwrB3HHyzkpUD1Du@YppZ8WkKIjhN2K9mv7RTk0J3mcGl/FRRDJN3Q7p6c94iZWaHTZfxhGlQk/DGa3RybRF2xzhMGb7ZlNfNtHMb5WusX)
[Try it online (Python 2, PyPy).](https://tio.run/##NYyxDsMgDET3fMUpWZKhUdsxcz@hUmfSWAWJ2IiAEF9PIVU92Kfz3XM5aOH7xWWXSxnw8iYQskSPt2wETZ6Wrs6Ah4AlIJ0JxbVo@IOVrCRUfcAaprkln5rgvOGAQ0u0WzsJ0XWnOfbtXwV556lu1O4RjLXwkblC5376YRpUxP0xNbsbVoG6pI0ljFbt66aW2zROy7WULw)
[Try it online (Python 3, CPython).](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsMwDET3fMXRLMkSWrpl7icUOjuNqA2OZBwbk6935ZRqkI7T3QtHssL3Wnu8okuEQ3LEW1aCpUhzp9PjIWBJKGfCsHYcf7CQlwLVO7xjmlryaQkhOk7YrWS/tlOQQ3eaw6X9VVAMkXRDu3ty3iNmZoVOl/GHaVCR8MdodnNsEnXFOk8YvNmW1cy3cRjna61f)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136720#136720)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 143 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136752/21194))

```
from sys import*
def l(*_):
 while 1:1
t=lambda*_:l;p=lambda*_:_[1][1]=="_"and l()or settrace(t)
def k(f):
 setprofile(p)
 try:f()
 finally:l()
```

The warmup was handled faster than expected, so let's go straight to the deep end. Pass one argument to `k` by appending code to this program. That argument may be initialized imperatively.

- Don't modify `k` or its dependencies before calling it; you must break `k` from within. Similarly, don't call `sys.setprofile` or perform other interpreter modifications when initializing the argument.
- No threads or processes may be spawned,
- The solution must run on CPython and PyPy,

[Try it online (CPython).](https://tio.run/##RYzNCgIhFIX3PsXFNjqLgWlpzDu0jxBrNIf843ojfHqzNsFZnHPg@0ojn9Oxd4c5Qm0V9lgy0sQ26yCISUvF4O33YGFRC6M1mHjbzKRVOJX/0JflOrKuXHOTtkHKjFAtEZq7FSR/vqdwX924C2Y3nKJIBoRNOTGK25MJoakBM3aAs6kVyFsw@HhFmwi8Rcuegs/zzGXvHw)
[Try it online (PyPy).](https://tio.run/##RYzLCsIwFET3@YpL3CQFC3UZ6T@4FynRJqY0L26uSL4@RjfCLGYGzsmVXIqnY665tmYxBSi1wBZyQhrYaix4MSxSMXi7zRuY1MRo9jrcVz0syp/zfyzX6dYzz3zhOq6dlAmhGCLUDyNI/ny7sF9dvzMm250iSwaEVVnRi92i9r6qDjN2gIsuBcgZ0Ph8BRMJnEHDdsHHceSytQ8)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/136752#136752)

Comment: @Veedrac I know you from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j__0bnudXnc), and I never thought I'd see another person with such obscure overlapping interests (SMM2 and code golf)!

Comment: @pxeger There's a difference?

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 77 bytes (safe)

```
extension Bool{prefix static func !(b:Bool)->Bool{return true}}
while !true{}
```

To solve this, put your code before or after this statement.

- Your solution must:

  - keep this statement intact, without modifying its code
  - actually let this statement run

    - Simply commenting it out, calling `fatalError()`, etc. before it doesn't count.
  - modify the behavior of this statement to prevent it from looping forever
- The solution does not involve crashing the program.

---

> This code is a refinement of [my previous (cracked) attempt, here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136343/11490)
>  The first line of this code exists solely to prevent the [exploit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136754/11490)
>  found by [@Veedrac](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21194/veedrac).
>  
>  `true` in `while !true` is not actually a `Bool`. It's a boolean
>  literal. Any type that conforms to [`ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebybooleanliteral)
>  can be initialized from a boolean literal. Usually, the correct
>  `ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral` to be instantiated is inferred from the
>  context where it's needed. If, such as in this case, the context does
>  not provide any type information as to the kind of
>  `ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral` needed, the compiler falls back to
>  choosing  `BooleanLiteralType` as the default.
>  
>  By default, the value of `BooleanLiteralType` is `Bool`. This makes
>  sense. In the absence of contextual type information, `true` and
>  `false` are both used to initialize instances of `Bool`. Interestingly,
>  `BooleanLiteralType` can be overridden locally. My solution exploits
>  this by creating a `ExploitBool` type, and sets it to be the preferred type for boolean literals, so the `true` in `while !true` is actually an instance of `ExploitBool`. I then define a prefix `!` operator, so that for all instances `x` of `ExploitBool`, `x` returns `true` as a `Bool`.
>
> ```
>     // First, set up the exploitive data type we need:
>     struct ExploitBool: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
>         init(booleanLiteral _: Bool) {
>             // ignore booleanLiteral, we don't care about it
>         }
>
>
>         // Define the prefix ! as an operator that acts on a ExploitBool,
>         // and always just returns false (as a regular Bool)
>         prefix static func !(b: ExploitBool) -> Bool {
>             return false
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     // Then, set it as the preferred type to instantiated from
>     //boolean literals in the absense of other contextual type information.
>     typealias BooleanLiteralType = ExploitBool
>
>
>     extension Bool{prefix static func !(b:Bool)->Bool{return true}}
>     while !true{}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

## BrainF - Cracked

```
,[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<[->+<]>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[.]
```

Should be easy to reverse engineer it.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177759/47990)

Comment: What's BrainF? Do you mean brainfuck?

Comment: Yes I do, but I do not like cursing.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 27 bytes, (Cracked by @DominicVanEssen in comments)

```powershell
while([int]($args[0])+1){1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vzwjMydVIzozryRWQyWxKL042iBWU9tQs9qw9v9/AA)

Should be very easy to crack!

Comment: Er, ```-1```.....?  Or is there something I didn't get?

Comment: @DominicVanEssen yes it is! You have cracked my answer!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 46 bytes, [cracked by EasyAsPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226120/78186)

```
def f(x):
 while isinstance(type(x),type):pass
```

I only ask that the function must actually be called: i.e., you can't just pass an object that calls `exit()` in `__init__`, because that would exit *before* execution of `f` began.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226120/94093). Not sure if it counts, though.

Comment: @EasyasPi my understanding of the challenge is that you find (or create) an **input** to the function that halts it. If that is the case, then you haven't actually cracked it.
you are *very much* on the right track though.

Comment: [like this?](https://tio.run/##TU3LCsQgDLz7FTkq9FDoTdhvkbS120DWChFWv97GU3uZIfPI5FbOKy297/GAw1bnDfxP4ggklKRg2qItLUe1psHOZxTpGytC1fQohkCJSghWRh@@fK3Irw@qPceH8bfuCHVqfjZGR61z/QY "Python 3 – Try It Online")?

Comment: @EasyasPi almost verbatim my solution. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 23 bytes (Safe)

```
'\\'/)2<'" '.@@++~{.}do
```

I hope I blocked everything except my intended solution... :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz0mRl1f08hGXUlBXc/BQVu7rlqvNiX//38A)

### Edit:

This solution is technically 'safe', but I think it doesn't deserve it.

First, the challenge was posted 3 years ago, so it was relatively inactive. Moreover, Golfscript is quite esoteric, so fewer people would have had to try solving it.

Below is the solution anyways. Please check it out to evaluate it yourself! :D

> Using the string interpolation trick, '#{' will generate an error.

Answer (score -1):

### CPython 3.6, <del>635</del> 634 bytes [Cracked](/a/135893/43394)

```
j=input()
__builtins__.__dict__["__import__"]=eval(j)
import random,functools,itertools,zlib
exec("@functools.lru_cache(None)\ndef f():i=input();return(all(x is y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest((x for x in sorted(dir(eval(i[::2])))if'_'not in x),sorted{}))\nand all(x is y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest((x for x in sorted(dir(eval(i[1::2])))if'_'not in x),sorted{}))and 8 and zlib.crc32(bytes(i,'ASCII'))==zlib.crc32(bytes(j,'ASCII')))".format(*eval('('+"(tuple(''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')for x in range%s)for x in range%s),),"%(("(random.randint(1,9))",)*2)*2+')')))
try:f()
except:f=bool
while not f():8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVKxTsMwEN3zFVakymewItEuEBQJxNSFhbFUVuI4zQXXDo5DkyK@vTitWgYGFiTLPt0933t@53b0tTWLw6HJ0LS9BxYJUfSoPZpOiESIEqUXYhULgdvWuhDH60x95BoaFp1SxOWmtFte9UZ6a3XH0St3ivYai0gNSkL8cKkn2vVC5rJW8GyNYq@mVBWpgKV4lnHvlO@dgVxrGAh2ZCSVdWTgI0FDLv2TPbZCW7NRnYcAPGImRBd0qRJKdHAUi6s0na8ZY1hRQY31E2hg/IT7/GJBRHgF@T@@m78IycR3e9wnlxLp5GIOxehVB8jp48vTckkZy7Jf1eanyuIkaNjmHq6OvBTodQy@b7UCSpPGooHTeBJZW5Qhmxcy2L2psXnTW2Pbd9f5/mM3jHvKLu8JdzZq1v1OcMbjGUB87jodaDzc8LsghrOreVjXlE3aIu/GNIw1fACpWp9WWRFMjHY1akUmS6aR3x4O3w)

It probably works in some other versions too, but I haven't tested it in them. Golfing advice welcome.

Note that triggering an `EOFError` is cheaty - this program expects streams to remain open!

I also have an ungolfed version, complete with terrible, terrible ASCII art, prettified output and probable cryptographic security.

```
import_input = input()
__builtins__.__dict__["__import__"] = eval(import_input)

import secrets
import functools
import itertools
import zlib
import base64

code = b"""
             GA2
   A      LGA  2     AL1ad        >eG
  @ >T   )Ec#  6     *  C       WM 2 +0    4.            ^1
 +   5  i      T    m   \'     J   ]   7  g                q
 e  `   -+     D V_4W  a ,    :C<  G  E*t
3   GW0P0V/bkg iU>       o    %hb  &  CM_
n      Y 1!SHJIUjh^     iZ    Ol5  %  =n4   Q`b   21   Z>A
R    l& j       iSDh  c>j  ;#  @h  E  ?l    B  W h  # u
di-90o @\\O"t6XNM8boo1T   /JHW     c        Y,@  H    N Ok
                        ?pDT:)     (        (    `    %  F
3<uEZ_BZ"\\hNA)a.1W_9\\)/e%/ROb    2        V     ?5   3q
c5g^O89kP>iuQ3`*GZHb>#u0%gcC_6(    i
L                           Es/    V
6                           >qD    m       H              6
,                           D;$    J        K            ,
                             :K    O              U   ?
                                 I0L(#               d
                                 =   C              9
                                                   `
f$g3<"""

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
make_keyword = lambda l:"".join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for x in range(l))
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.a85decode(code)[::-1]).decode("ASCII").format(
    *eval('('+"(tuple(make_keyword(secrets.randbelow(20)+1)"
                "for x in range(secrets.randbelow(20)+1)),),"*2+')')))

try:
    f()
except:
    f = bool

while not f():
    print(secrets.randbelow(2), end="")

for byte in itertools.zip_longest(
    *(iter(bin(int.from_bytes(code, "big"))[2:]),) * 8, # bits in a byte
    fillvalue = 0):
    print("".join(byte), end="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVT/W9o@EP49f8UtztEAlm/KlCmTCR/Rj8o2p2yIhn4JEClNbdMp/vMuKdShm@6ep@ndm7s3d5f2gpkcC7/y8MCngQgl5X4QS9iB5G0QRKkdc09yP6LUpNTljqT0AlO68Kf4Unmzn5ZnLDMQhOYmRMwJmYxScxj7jhTCewS4ZOET4N7jdqrbVsSq6wg5wmXqGBtjjGBZ9htlDTTm1tG@UsqJ2jgqWW7qVWf7ymsX6t@UQVrOCkA12cgC7C18uscqMlfU6rq5fMRVCUFOvTcA@BzRLDBVTz@T2IfquVTPe4ARPJMbBAxgoLS1XAI04ZyudwEsyGuztretqgBoZSWq6IK6xc/F84I9GQE/qy9IhF5WxzbAO5XwMUX@HP8BpTen7cODs@vxVQLwnl47nsp1FWDHX1fWl4GKg3JJLb16A33VHt47uF5w89PmGMCpK/uD6suuMloAHz2990m1BRSwAjFy@dpWUcBuv9/Bsvr95HjTFqKkW1E4bHcTKict@kd@F6CttRPoTBC8IB@D5rcaSVQjxRJlkNQL8B@qbMetHv3Uw/3@@KRBLLPUpVv9Pimw1cLXji5scd9Kzuekqnao3CBnY3TV2dyafK7z@EtlkN3vte36SlxcHTl7tJocw9ERvCytqJCwouorTvWbZvoxaGk/3a2i/CuxzQ9v068nkf@XN/MIXpNa4tx5Cp7p8l@P03JQPDJWnmHuv8N24PfPspCtf0f9KQM0fDuqbOtfGVleMLZspgcOtmzHZcPRmF9PvKkvgpswkvHP27vZPUZTa8LohM1uRegqX8@a2q4FXg1j81pw31gMGdMZC@4wI6UlMBQh3KlhBqHlj5jhEYLYHXMMPWRMlzliGoQsioz5oDGtzQ0NuszQC7mo1dZKl8RcYLhxundwgImpWKeWNJLqs8nsyxiZHDZkHHjMWE72MTN1vmszT9wa5SLJlQj@o3X4Wa4vRZI8yeNsOZchGaLKQTKc1RKyoaGLc1ggF7aemGqyInQ75h4DX0jtM98MQu7Lv51B8sB8dwdjRa0zsmeS6aQe57R5zwPqCZVilLbA0JuGrS5CkZrDUEypDouSLuYB23yECbko1y5V8mrobubVSLG5jDSxlRwxz5h7nupmrGd98Umi6UVr16UMHx5@AQ)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135893#135893)

Comment: `eval`ing code directly from input without error handling is a trivial way to get cracked

Comment: @ppperry [Rematch?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135896/43394)