# Restricted mini challenges Robbers Thread

Tags: sequence, restricted-source, cops-and-robbers

> [Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread)

Your task as robbers is to find cops solutions and write a program in the language provided that computes the nth term of the sequence using only the bytes in the provided set.

The goal will be to crack as many cops answers as possible.  With each crack awarding you a single point.

Cracks need not be the cop's intended solution as long as they work.

Comment: A robber leaderboard would be nice.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder If you want to make one be my guest, I don't do JavaScript so I will not be adding one myself.

Answer (score 15):

## [Haskell, xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136239/3852)

```hs
s=show s
ss=show[[s]]
w h=[ss!!h]<show[h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcmxDsIgFEbhnaf4m3SARElZnMQn0Kkj3oHEJjRtKenFwNuj0e3kO8HzMq1ra2w57AUs@F/OMZEoCNYxd12g608Dtc3PERavXQDpncd83CN6ZL9MMMMA5u/YfHpApmOOGRryWXG@QdYTCqpSCs5obS7UPg)

The first line defines `s` as the fixed point of the `show` function, which is the infinite string

```hs
"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\...
```

It has `"`s at indices 0, 2, 6, 14, 30… Powers of two, minus two.

The second line defines `ss` as the string

```hs
[["\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\...
```

It has non-`\`s at indices 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32… Powers of two, ignoring 0.

We’re in luck: in ASCII, `"` < `[` < `\`, so we can write an indicator function for the less-than-backslashes in this string, and we’re done!

`w h` is our answer: it checks if the `h`’th element of `ss` is less than a backslash. Well, we can’t construct a string containing only a backslash, so we construct some other string that’s always bigger than `"["`, namely `show[h]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136187/31957)

Anonymous function.

```matlab
@(_)_^('^'/'/')
```

### Explanation

```matlab
@(_)_^('^'/'/')
@(_)                  % anonymous function taking argument `_`
    _^                % that argument raised to the power of
       '^'            % 94
          /           % divided by
           '/'        % 47
                      % (94 / 47 == 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mG/PfQSNeMz5OQz1OXR8INf@naRhr/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (ES6), Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136238)

```
$=>eval(`${$}${atob(`ICo=`)}${$}`)
```

Outputs `0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...`.

Naming the input `$` makes it look a bit more complex than it has to be. `atob('ICo=')` evaluates to `*` with leading space (found that by hand). This makes `` ${$}${atob(`ICo=`)}${$} `` be `n *n` where `n` is input. `eval`ing gives the square.

```js
function t(){Array(10).fill(0).map((_,i)=>console.log(f(i)))}

f=

$=>eval(`${$}${atob(`ICo=`)}${$}`)

;t()
```

Comment: Well done! (My intended solution is a bit shorter, but that's the idea.)

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks! Now I'm curious :)

Comment: I had `a=>eval(\`a${atob\`ICo\`}a\`)`. Of course, any other letter can be used as the input variable. (Even if you want to use `$`, you don't need to do `${$}`.)

Comment: @Arnauld Oh wow, `${$}` is indeed pretty dumb.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136167/34388)

Very suboptimal though. Code:

```python
a=sum((()or()))
s=g=int(not(a))
for m in range(input()):a,s,g=s,g,sum((s,g))
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDoAgDEV3T8HYJgzqaNLDdFBkoCUFBk@P1eEn7yfv1affKvucTG0UAEA1QMSlUaIsHUQ7sP9LLZSQJRhLOiFLHd3Fg2OLiXzx7x1crvaljHNu6ws)

Comment: I was so close, didn't figure out `and` and `not` with `()` to make `1` and `0`. :(

Comment: good, but not the intended solution though

Comment: I did notice `import` was availabe, as well as `from`

Comment: @Rod Fixed the `d`, but is it necessary to use all bytes at least once?

Comment: You don't have to use all, so this answer is valid again c: , if want another challenge there is [new version that won't allow `sum`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136177)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136508/34531)

```
one=product(map(pred)mempty)
zero=pred(one)
add(a)(b)|a==zero=b|True=add(pred(a))(addone(b))
addone(x)=ao(x)(enumFrom(x))
ao(x)(y)|x==pred(head(y))=head(y)|True=ao(x)(drop(product(map(pred)mempty))y)
t(x)|x==zero=zero|x==one=one|True=add(t(pred(x)))(t(pred(pred(x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU@7DsIwDNz5igwM8VJV7F75AjbE4BJLrWgeCqnUov57cNICC0Oss@/su/T0fPA45uwdY4jeTPekLQUdIhuwbENa4PDi6LFMtMjgQMZoAt3BSoiV69ZLnBgLUWUEoKURtajqQoEzIHmpmt1kz9FbwULW0QLrjJtHz2SkB9zBfrvKTPQl2/@cIFGTqMqlGquU0pTPyfuFTFtMsYcP/g4gWxqcQhXi4JI6KrFRSV3bpjm1t/wG)

Note: the `product(map(pred)mempty)` in line 5 is different to line 1, because the former is of type `Int` whereas the latter is of type `Integer`.

Comment: Oh `mempty`! Next time I say `Haskell 98`... Can you do without `y`? But using `product` is the main idea, so I think I don't start a new version of this challenge. And I wished there was (or I could set) a time limit. BTW, `ao` looks unnecessary complicated.

Comment: @ChristianSievers: yes, `ao` is superfluous, because `addone(x)=head(drop(product(map(pred)mempty))(enumFrom(x)))`. And `one(x)=product(enumFromTo(x)(pred(x)))` where `x` is the input number, but that doesn't work for the `1` used with `drop`.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136647/34531)

```
t = let _:i:_ = [0..] in let n ee ll tt = let _:_:ii:_ = [ee,tt..] in ee : n ll tt ii in (n 0 i i !!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc1LCoAwDIThq4zgQkGkuCz0JCLSRcBgWorm/jU@wN3w88Fs8dxJpFZFgJBi9exX27MbxwWcn5hBBBHor8x9kGhQ/bAxb/qlzHfqMhxsoWn6mqKVgHJwVrRIsUCfq8kt9QI)

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136914/34531)

```
head.maybe[]id.head[head[flip lookup.zip[head[pred.pred.pred.floor]pi..]].map pure][head[pred.floor]pi..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBDoAgDAS/0oPnRh/gS0gPGEpoRGhQD/p5RD3oZZLdnWyw68wx1urHwNbhYo@JDYnDO5oHPopCzHneFU/Rt9TCDj/4thdSQSRqJwq6F6af@hPqYiXBCFokbdDBrXswA@LQU70A)

Comment: Wow, so many functions in the Prelude! I was beginning to believe this might stay uncracked... BTW, my solution is slightly shorter

Comment: @ChristianSievers: I've found your challenge 5 days after you've posted it and it took some time to get the all the `head` in the right place. Like all your other challenges, it was quite some fun.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2, Bruce Forte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136619/70424)

```
f=lambda m:-m==m or m*f(m-bool(m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIddKN9fWNlchv0ghVytNI1c3KT8/RyNXU/N/QVFmXolCmoa55n8A)

Wow. This was a fun one.

Answer (score 2):

## [R, Jarko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136155/58974)

I don't know R at all, so this is just a guess.

```
identity
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/MyU1rySzpPJ/moaF5n8A)

Comment: You got it! Maybe that was too easy...

Comment: @JarkoDubbledam, if a guy who never touched R before this got it the, yeah, it was definitely too easy! :p

Comment: Eh, its just a matter of finding the right function. Now if only R didn't give their functions a name related to what theyre doing....

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [Jarko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136172/67312)

```r
f=function(n)`if`(n,n*f(n-n**(n-n)),n**n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP08jTzMhMy1BI08nTytNI083T0sLRGpqAvlaeZr/ixMLCnIqNQysDA100jT/AwA)

Definitely took me a good five minutes to try and figure out how to get `1` from the letters, but then I remembered that `**` is `^` so that worked out nicely! (and `0^0=1` in R)

Comment: Well whaddaya know, `**=^`. Didn't know that.

Comment: I intended `n==n` btw.

Comment: `f=function(n,c=n==n)'if'(n,f(n-(n==n),c*n),c*(n==n))`

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam well nice to know there are two solutions here

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam also, from the R docs: "`**` is translated in the parser to `^`, but this was undocumented for many years. It appears as an index entry in Becker et al (1988), pointing to the help for Deprecated but is not actually mentioned on that page. Even though it had been deprecated in S for 20 years, it was still accepted in R in 2008." so it's not exactly as if it's well-known

Comment: As an R noob, I did the reverse. Also I was stumped because I didn't know about backtick notation:`f=function(n)'if'(n-n==n,n**n,n*f(n-(n**(n-n))))`

Comment: @Giuseppe well, Ive been using R since 2011 and didn't know about it :o

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents, Step Hen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136189/34388)

This seems to do the trick:

```
:1+z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/38pQu@r/f0NTAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [dj0wns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136203/31957)

```c
??=import<stdlib.h>
int main(int a,char**f)<%int h=""==" ",o=""=="",c=h,p=o,m=(int)atof(*(f+o));for(;p<=m;p++)c+=m%p==h;printf("%i",c);%>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5bCsMgFAX/u4pwQfCVfhaCucla7C1GIUYxrr9W6d8MnIFD80HU2r5jiDmVut71c4b302@PcNUp2nDxAVaTt0VKJ1Y23CMAIkyg059AE3qdMemIoxC2JscldyoJYVwq3OQVo8lKCVIYWUb0Jpc@dRxY6L0wbGutvb7kTnvcbe5fkJblBw) Digraphs, digraphs everywhere!

Comment: z is not in the bytespace but you have plenty of other letters you can use. Well done!

Comment: @dj0wns Ah! True enough, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136220/6828)

With -n flag,

`p$./$$`

This is my guess for the intended solution. Ignores the input and just outputs the floor of 1/the process id. Since the process id generally can't be 0 or 1, this should always be 0.

Comment: Yep, there it is :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136250/20260)

```hs
a(n)|pred(pred(abs(n)))==abs(pred(pred(n)))=sum(map(a)(enumFromTo(pred(pred(n)))(pred(n))))|()==()=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1EjT7OmoCg1RQNMJCYVAwU0NW1tQSyEOFisuDRXIzexQCNRUyM1rzTXrSg/NyQfTRGCpVmjATQGiPP@5yZm5inYKhQUZeaVKKgoAM1QSFSINtDTMzSI/Q8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136274/71256)

```
u(n)|negate(n)==(n)=negate(pred(n))|True=head(drop(length(enumFrom()))(enumFrom(n)))
g(a)(x)|null(x)=a|True=g(u(a))(drop(length(enumFrom()))x)
p(a)(b)=pred(g(rem(b)(b))(enumFromTo(negate(b))(a)))
a(n)|negate(n)==n||u(negate(pred(n)))==n=n|True=p(a(pred(pred(n))))(a(pred(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU8xDoMwDNx5RYYO9oLoA7L2BWxVB1dYATUJUUokBv6eOkCLhFTJinN3yZ3d0/vF1uacwOPi2dDEctO6HDsMkTuBuLQxse6ZOujiGMCyN1MP7JO7xdEBIh5A3mNlgBBm8U3WSte0WRhIIuBflxmrUH4@Ua/ZBiI7QVJHQjvCPl9hqcTRaQe/LAlOSxRahHUOCdn4n4hfpoDsaPBKqxAHP6mLchQUqXtT19fmkT8)

Finally fixed it for Integers rather than Ints. Very slow.

Comment: The task challenge demands that "Answers must be capable of calculating every term in the b-files of the sequence", and the b-file for A000045 goes up to 2000th Fibonacci number, which is much more than `maxBound::Int`, so I think this is not correct.

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that.

Comment: Well done! Now, can you do it without `g`? - BTW, you could have used `u(n)=negate(pred(negate(n)))`

Comment: I knew there was a better way to write `u`, I wish I thought of that. I don't know how to do it without `g`, I found it really hard to define addition for Integers with your byteset.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136344/56725)

If returning an `Int` is good enough, this does it:

```
_F _N=[_N,[_N,[_N..]!!_N..]!!_N..]!!_N
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, [iovoid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136317/72685)

```
$=>-(-($===-$))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQy@xjQxbSr627iFksxIVG11/v3fnLswx9Xu52VHcQkJ2REUSEgchPG6gSk25rTFSsT2t1aXYhoIZAlPwH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), [Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136421/69481)

```
&>:1-:v
 ^    _$v
        >\:v
        ^ *_$.@
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83OylDXqoxLIU4BCOJVgCwosIuxQnDiFLTiVfQc/v83AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [Jarko, again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136413/67312)

```r
cat(diag(diag(('i'%in%'i'):(x=scan()),x%x%x)),sep='')
```

This differs from Jarko Dubbeldam's intended solution, but the general idea is the same: to generate `1:n` repeated `1:n` times, it leverages `diag` in two different ways:

- `diag(matrix)` returns the diagonal of a matrix.
- `diag(vector, nrow)` generates an `nrow`x`nrow` matrix with `vector` along the diagonal, recycling as necessary.

`%x%` is the Kronecker matrix product which when applied to two numbers returns their usual product.

Finally, `cat` prints the diagonal out with `sep`arator `''` which results in the sequence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMlMzEdQmioZ6qrZuapAilNK40K2@LkxDwNTU2dClUgBNLFqQW26uqa/83@AwA)

Comment: That's (almost) it, but close enough to count it as intended :)

Answer (score 2):

### C, [Yimin Rong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136677/56725)

```
long long t(long long n, long o){
  return o ? t(n,--o)-(-n) : o;
}
long long r(long n, long o){
  return --o ? t(r(n,o),n) : n;
}
long long g(long n){
  return n ? r(n,n) : -(--n);
}
```

`t` is multiplication, `r` is exponentiation, `g` is the real function. Newlines added for readability, they aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), [Christian Sievers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136717/56433)

```hs
___ __=[__-__,[[[__..]!!__..]!!__..]!!__..]!!__-[[__..]!!__..]!!__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU3LCoMwELz3K1booYVs0E1i9OCXBLt4KFSqQdr@fzp6LYVl57Ez7GN6P@/LUtZpzjTQ9przh860ThupKqXa2qYby85Vh6TKqiYlEGvHqvoD/BsozGSN8pBorE4Q@eIzuyue@nwTdnk3a0MNBiDRUBBDXYCWFiuCiYMlPW4uIuQD0sGDtQ5e9EcBuT7ujaY@yl7KFw)

Comment: Right. Did I manage to make you think "no identifiers?" for a moment? - My solution is `__ ___=[-___-___-___,___..]!!___`

Answer (score 2):

## [R by Jarko Dubbeldam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136476/48198)

Took me a while since I don't know R and I didn't manage to use `t` twice:

```r
cos(pi*(t=scan())/2)/abs(cos(pi*t/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzm/WKMgU0ujxLY4OTFPQ1NT30hTPzGpWAMqUQLka/43@A8A)

#### Explanation

It uses the fact that `cos(t*pi/2)` has a period of `4` in `t` and the sequence starts with: [1, 6.123234e-17, -1, -1.83697e-16]. As you can see the signs are correct, so we just need to normalize the values but keeping the sign - that's what `x/abs(x)` does for `x != 0`.

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCsMwDATveYXwSUoPhvRWyC/6AcdxiSGVjKVC83onTdvjzrDsls0W4Wtr02ZJk8EIzjmk3o9DmGJmKWoH6booc/raKIol92ijxsBI5AfyYVL8CTsynZ1SMxu6@5IgyrOEmlUYarJX5TTfwF3UKoZ1xTdkhv@Hh1Q4wWeTiFrbAQ)

Comment: now I don't understand how R binds variables at all anymore.......Also it's pretty funny how the floating point imprecision makes this feasible!

Comment: In C an assignment returns the value that gets assigned, so I guess that's what R is doing here too.

Comment: @Giuseppe This works, unless you're in a function call. `cos(t=scan())` wouldn't work because R can't distinguish between `=` for assignment or for argument specification. In braces however, this is not a problem: `cos((t=scan()))`, but this is longer than `cos(t<-scan())`, so not used when golfing.

Comment: Also nice job, exactly what I had in mind :D

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam the function call was the thing that's messing with me.

ALSO despite my best efforts I couldn't solve it because I was *so sure* that the `*` was a red herring and `cospi` actually correctly calculates `cos(pi/2)=0`...and this will be 1-indexed with `sin` rather than `cos`

Comment: @Giuseppe That is amazing, I was looking for that function but couldn't find it XD. Already thought it was weird that they wouldn't implement an option for radians.

Answer (score 2):

## [CPython 3.6, by wizzwizz4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread/136699#136699) (A000002)

```
t=int().__sub__(int()==int())
t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));
t=int().__sub__(t).__sub__(int()==int())
d=__builtins__.__dict__;l=list(d);
c=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
_=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
dd=d[l[_]].__dict__
ll=list(dd)
d[l[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](dd[ll[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](d[l[_]](),(d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))))))
```

I manually wrote the lines up until `ll=list(dd)`, but the rest of the code was generated by this python program:

```
def construct_number(n):
    return "d[l[t]](("+",".join(("d",)*n)+"))"
def construct_character(n):
    return "d[l[c]]("+construct_number(ord(n))+")"
def construct_string(n):
    return "dd[ll[%s]](d[l[_]](),(%s))"%(construct_number(24),",".join(map(construct_character, n)))
def construct_code(code):
    return "\nd[l[%s]](%s)"%(construct_number(19),construct_string(code))
code = construct_code("""def k(n):
 v=1;s=[1,1,2];c=1;r=1
 for _ in range(n):
  for _ in range(s[c]):
   if r>=len(s):s.append(v)
   r+=1
  c+=1;v=(v%2)+1
 return s[n]
print(k(int(input())))""")
```

The generated code could almost certainly be golfed better, but that would make the generator code more complicated.

Comment: Hey! You automated the problem. :-p I'll mark it once I've tested.

Comment: Is there some reason I can't use automation?

Comment: No reason at all. I did the same - although golfier I feel that my solution was more hackish and much less elegant than yours. A combination of the two would be _really_ golfy.

Answer (score 2):

## [CPython 3.6, by wizzwizz4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread/136782#136782) (A000796)

```
t=int().__sub__(int()==int())
t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));
t=int().__sub__(t).__sub__(int()==int())
d=__builtins__.__dict__;l=list(d);
c=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
_=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
dd=d[l[_]].__dict__
ll=list(dd)
d[l[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](dd[ll[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](d[l[_]](),(d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))))))
```

This time, the generated code is almost twice as long.

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript (ES6) by Draco18s](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137862/21173)

The solution is whatever [jsfuck.com](http://jsfuck.com) returns when given:

```
f=function(n){return 2**n;}
```

The full source is 30739 characters long:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]])+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]))()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136171/63641)

```python
n=int(input())
l=[1,2,2]
for i in range(2,n):l+=[1+i%2]*l[i]
print(l[:n+1][n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu9CoAgFAbQ3adwCTRdtCbBJ5E7NPRzQT5FbOjprebDqU@/CpYxEBldMerdldYix@Sst57EUZpkyZBtw7krb6FDNh8bnjzNOTGJ2v6cU4BxlEB6jPUF)

Comment: Yeah, I probably shouldn't have posted my solution from the OEIS challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread/136179#136179)

```python
f=lambda x:x<1or f(x-1)*x
c=lambda n:(f(2*n)/f(n)/f(n+1))**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NckxDoAgDADA3VcwtlWjMBJ9DKKoiRRCHOrrcTAut1x@7iOxqTXMl4vL6pRYmXQqKoD0Gkka/w9bCGCIcQjw0WpEIlNzOflW0WXwnSqO9w30iFhf)

We really should stop posting our answers from the previous OEIS challenge :)

Comment: That's the only tricky one I have lol. :P

Comment: @totallyhuman Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136177/53880)

```python
n=input()
l=[]
p=[n]
for i in range(n):
 lp=[]
 for t in l:
  lp[:len([])]=[n]
 for t in p:
  lp[:len([])]=[n]
 (l,p)=(p,lp)
print len(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcsxDsIwEETRfk@x5a6UAigj@SSWC4oAllaTkWUKTm9iGpq0/83w0187bmMgVfDdzSVSLsKUUeSxN61aoe2O52bwVTQ4XSf1SXG0I@Y1NlguXn7Pv/PcLRZ6Mi5BF7aKrnMQPsb18gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [Bobawob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136180/63641)

```python
print '1'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQd1QXSszr6C0REPz/38jAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2, totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136191/34388)

```python
p=int(input())
print(128*p**2+2336*p+10657)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIxDU0stAq0NIy0jYyNjbTKtA2NDAzNdf8/98EAA)

Comment: Ninja'd me by 2 seconds. You do not need `int(...)`

Comment: Hehe totallyhuman ninja'd you on the "cracked" link.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh yeah you're right haha, I was confused with Python 3 :P

Comment: The ninja'ing [seems to happen more often than you would think](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135365/will-it-halt-robbers/135849?noredirect=1#comment332249_135849) :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136191/31516)

```python
n=input()
print(128*n*n+2336*n+10657)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRMPQyEIrTytP28jY2AxIGRqYmZpr/v9vDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly, fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136196/34388)

```
1ṁḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4c7Ghzt6/v//bw4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [Jarko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136205/67312)

```r
function(n)n%o%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTzNPNV81739xYkFBTqWGgZWhgU6a5n8A)

anonymous function. `%o%` is the outer product of two vectors, but when `n` is of length one, this is just the normal product :)

Comment: Exactly correct!

Answer (score 1):

### [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), [sonar235](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72175/sonar235)

108868716804073523295 0s.

Corresponding brainfuck:

```
-[----->+<],>--<[>.<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1oXBOy0bWJ17HR1baLt9Gx0Y///twcA)

Takes input as a character

Comment: This pretty obviously does not work for values over 255.  And the b files have up to 1000

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby, Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136220/34388)

Not sure if this is correct, but it seems to work :p

```ruby
p$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BF7/9/UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) by [theLambGoat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136225/9365)

```perl
$t=<>;$t=~m;()()()()()()(.);;print$7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lxNbGzhpI1uVaa2giQT1Na@uCosy8EhXz//8NAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136197/3852)

```
{{)_%)}%si}
```

Computes `[(x+1)%(x+1)+1 for x in [0..n−1]]`, turns that into a string, turns that into an int.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7paM15Vs1a1OLP2v6FxTN1/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python, Step Hen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136217/3852)

```python
l=lambda a:a+a-1+l(a-1) if a else a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1kjJzE3KSVRIS21OFNb19bQwEqTK8cWKpholaidqGuonaMBJDUVMtMUEhVSc4pTFRL/FxRl5pVo5GhYamr@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (ES6), Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136246)

```
$=>$+++$
```

Outputs `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...`

```js
function t(){Array(10).fill(0).map((_,i)=>console.log(f(i)))}

f=

$=>$+++$

;t()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [Azulflame](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136284/53748)

```python
print(sum([g[0]for g in filter(all,[[n]+[n%p for p in range(1+1,n)]for n in range(1+1,10000000)])][:int(input())]))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BboMwDIbvPEWEVJEUNCWbqopOPWyvYeWQgYFIqROFoG5Pzwjjspv12f78O/ykydPb2vke71VVrSFaSnxeHhxGkHrwkY3MEhusSxi5ca4BIF0DnQLL3ZC70dCIXNWqIbHv0H@qpJRCCw23bLcUlsTFBsS63Sw2qX9in@9/DcvTC3qoCe481e/SFLMdTyE2zOFN52n8xo7nvKL4CwvlpyHCnnWTiTNbZuzLpvxw7gCHvtSwVbzLyQ60P7CD3adFcSjVa9teZXs@v1zEepG/)**

`10000000` replaced with `1000` to allow code to run within the timeout limit - one thousand is greater than the 50th prime, 229; ten million is greater than the hundred thousandth prime, 1299709.

Also checks the characters.

Comment: That works for select values. I'll verify that it matches the b-file when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), [Step Hen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136157/63641)

```
;-\1$
=-1:-$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/31o3xlCFy1bX0EpX5f9/SwA)

The `-` threw me off at first.

Comment: I like that solution. I edited in my intended solution - I think you might appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [Azulflame](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136330/20260)

```python
n=int(input())
p=int()
i=p**p
t=(i--i)**-i
u=(i--i--i)**-i
print(int(n*t)-int(n*u))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcsxCsBACAXR3pP4BasUqbxPbIwELfb0BrKQbl4xueq645gJ8yj2yC4GKD@C3FIkqYxd1SGiTr3xO5@9FocUdEcDM@cL)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript, Ra8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136314/41805)

```
$=_=>_?--_?$(_)-(-$(--_)):_-~_:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBDkAwDADQn@mhzVLhuhmf0ggjFVHZxNGvj3d7@/RMZc563XzakmqFKHGQkVlGQCFGBvxD5IVf8VJXy6ixDdp3baDZzmJHag7bEFCdIwr1Aw)

Comment: There's no `+` in the byteset. Replace it with `-(-...)`

Comment: @Birjolaxew Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript, iovoid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136317/41805)

```
R=a=>(a==a>a)-(a>a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcRRCoAgDADQ62yIYd82D@ENhlksxIVG11/0Pt7FL88y5H58172aZWJKwEScGD3826EDhEKUbQ0Ri/aprS5NT8ggziFG@wA)

Comment: Damn, you were a minute faster :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Ruby, Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136268/3808)

```
$_=[$m.to_s.to_i..$_.to_i][$m.to_s.to_i].sum
```

Comment: Nice alternate method of obtaining `0`! My intended solution used a slightly different method, but hey, whatever works

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2, Bobawob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136406/3852)

```
print(2**(2**input()))
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Ew0hLC4Qz8wpKSzQ0NTX//zcDAA)

Comment: Damn, got beaten by the comment thingy... :(

Comment: It seems that @JarkoDubbeldam beat you to this but it was converted to a comment.  I'm not sure what the ruling would be here.

Comment: @WheatWizard meh, just leave it as is :)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [Jarko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136332/67312)

```r
cat(t(col(diag(scan()))),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKNEIzk/RyMlMzFdozg5MU9DEwh0ilMLbNXVNf@b/gcA)

Comment: Interesting, not what I intended :o But I do see that there are some unnecessary bytes in my set.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam well now I *have* to know what your solution was.

Comment: [Why don't you try for yourself?
 ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136413/59530)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), [geokavel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136289/53880)

```
{{)}%1+{*}*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/ulqzVtVQu1qrVqv2f13BfzMA)

Comment: You solution's actually much simpler than mine. I think it's cause I thought `0,` outputs nothing, not an empty array, so I did a bunch of workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, geokavel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136289/3852)

```
{{)}%1+{*}*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7pas1bVULtaq1ar9r95TN1/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), [Bobawob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136423/72043)

```
'"'""""""""""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X11JXQkO/v83BAA)

The above is 1-indexed. Since the 0-index was requested:

```
'"'""'""""""""""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X11JXQmEYOD/fzMA)

Returns the Nth term of [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027), where N is entered into STDIN

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/LOLCODE), [Bobawob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136434/72043)

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A HAT
GIMMEH HAT
HAT R PRODUKT OF HAT AN HAT
VISIBLE HAT
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz4jLU8HDMVjBEUiGcLl7@vq6eoCZQKwQpBAQ5O8S6h2i4O8GElRw9APLhXkGezr5uILZ3iEeEU6Rrv//mxoAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Seed, TehPers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136460/3852)

```
3 4353323
```

Corresponds to the Befunge program `&.@`.

Comment: Nice! My solution wasn't anywhere near as short or pretty as yours.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave by Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136499/48198)

Straight forward recursive fibonacci:

```matlab
function f = fi(c)
  one = cond(e);                       % construct a value for 1 (e is invertible)
  f = one-one;                         % set return value to 0
  if c                                 % if c != 0
    f = one;                           %   set return value to 1
    if c-one                           %   if c != 1
      f = fi(c-one)-(-fi(c-one-one));  %     recursive calls with c-1 & c-2
    end
  end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY47CoAwDEB3T5GxAQu6KoL3EIcSG@iSgqjg6WtS0SGf99KGZDrCFUvhU@hIWYBhAk6OsAHIEpUoy@YijipsqNJrGCYG0vL7sYJZe1EB/oWm0Dv/9ZXx/RJla96sUcK@h1sPcjOnFpZu6LsVywM)

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##PY8xDsMgDAB3XmExYVVM3Rqlr@gHWjAKUmoiQqTm9RQTJYOBOxuwl71Mie@1fvZCKxUYQWutwKAdxqfzFCKnsimRyiVPR0HY2JWYGELjEI1DBZBYsi6xN4RDE5Js0rYQjAFc2y4/dBArFR3gelAUWmPPc2c8rhB7dawtemdLjlyMfk3U/v8u7xzX1lymsmUm/wB9W0s273k2P4gM57AhZehCJkPEWv8)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sure, fixed. I'm curious about your solution now.

Comment: My solution is basically the same, but messier. I made it before I realized I needed `e` and `d` in `end` (stupid me). So I had `not(not(i))` to get `1` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

### C, [theLambGoat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136492/56725)

```
int r(int n){
  return 5-5<n-n/5-n/5-n/5-n/5-n/5 ? 5-5 : r(n/5)-5/5;
}

int t(int n){
  return n<5 ? 5-5 : t(n-5/5)-r(n);
}
```

`r` is a helper function returning`-e` where `5^e` is the highest power of 5 dividing `n`. `t` is the function computing the sequence.

Comment: if someone insists on no newline, I can easily put it in one line...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2 by Arnold Palmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136306/48198)

Replace `/2` by `>>1`, use `&1` to check parity, `2 > n` instead of `n == 1` and `n+n+n` instead of `3*n` - that's basically it:

```python
def fun(n):
  if 1+1>n:
    return 1-1
  if n&1:
    return 1+fun(n+n+n+1)
  return 1+fun(n>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0xCsMwFEP3nEJTsLE7qGMH36UQO/WimI8z9PQuSaYGLUIP8dq3fzY9x1hyQdnl5F8TUAsYmHR0wHLfTeCDF9LMfxDOZzhCP933lOhH2QxCFeytNTtG8jQ1q@pO8XL78QM)

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##XY@9CsMwDIR3P4XwEGzcDKJboH6KbqVDGsvEkMrBcaB5ejc/7dCiRdx3QnfjkvvI51IeS6aJMlxASmmmOp8YZpF0QOXs3d8aqlYgRBcdHSZHHvzMinUjAIIHNGh52wES5TkxYI0H4gp/gdkvzTaoxb9uLer925gCZyWvPUEXn2ObwhT5YybXwJo0J9UOg3pBYPiW8DHBLmxptdalvAE)

**Note**: <s>This assumes that the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) holds true since it won't terminate & return `-1` if `1` is never reached (I hope this is ok :P).</s> The [b-file of A006577](https://oeis.org/A006577/b006577.txt) only goes up to `10000` and these  values always terminate.

Comment: The assumptions here is fine.  Since you need only work for all the values in the b-files.

Comment: Right, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, [Евгений Новиков](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136503/65836)

```
~NaN+1
```

I'm assuming this is the console, since I don't think you can do I/O with this byteset. So apparently `~NaN` is `-1` 0.o

Answer (score 1):

## [`dc` by Yimin Rong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136554/48198)

Since the function is not computable and there are only `5` values in the [b-file](https://oeis.org/A028444/b028444.txt), the easiest way is probably to do a Lagrange interpolation, the interpolating polynomial is:

This is essentially what the following `dc` code does:

```
?dd*dd*3*r53*+2/rddd**8rr3+*r5rr8+*+-2rr2+/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoMwEAXRnlN8WS5gV4jIJhJKilyEBlgj3NhkoczdHUvTvFmX6yhlz4qImGDbK3zxwNi9IbkBTo3p3mFsfM23bcN2ZNiIH2RDH2A@IlTzpE9P7AaVKppUPdelOjFx71QdD6fp5mQaySmUMv4B)

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##NU5LCoMwFNx7ikdW@SCCwRIK4iV6AWtSDNgkjCnU06eppTCb@TGTjrzGoEu5H9ntLtNIjLF26qTq9XAxNqHyplmidT9vslZWaIlB11AHW5k0gFZVAoySqu2BXnXprCb4kDm7rY6W@Ewz/B4DweUXgrNXYmrP4PO28Tf5QP8jjwg6he@0EKKUDw)

Answer (score 1):

### Ly, [LyricLy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136517/56725)

```
01n[1-sp<l>[s<1>=[<1+>p=]p<l>]<0r]prpJu
```

You'll have to copy the code yourself, but there is an [online interpreter](https://lylang.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Nice work! An improvement from my solution.

Answer (score 1):

### [JavaScript (ES6), ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136842/9365)

I learnt a new thing through this, I didn't know JS supported the `\u0000` literals as executable code!

````js
\u0046u\u006e\u0063\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e`\u0046u\u006e\u0063\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e\u0028\u0027\u0077\u0069\u006e\u0064\u006f\u0077\\u005\u0062\u00288897540\u002e5\u002f\u002e5\u0029\u002e\u0074\u006f\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u002836\u0029\\u005\u0064\u0028\u0077\u0069\u006e\u0064\u006f\u0077\\u005\u0062\u0028779076608\u002e5\u002f\u002e5\u0029\u002e\u0074\u006f\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u002836\u0029\\u005\u0064\u0028\u0029\u00252\u0029\u0027\u0029\u0028\u0029```
````

My first task was to extract the usable chars from the restrictions put in place: `` \ #$%&'()./023456789>?@BCDEFGHINOPRSTUVWXY^_`bcdefghinoprstuvwxy~ `` then work back a solution from there. I thought I was close a few times, but finally settled on a solution of:

````js
Function`Function('window\\u005b(8897540.5/.5).toString(36)\\u005d(window\\u005b(779076608.5/.5).toString(36)\\u005d()%2)')()```
````

where the `[` and `]` had to be double escaped since the `b` and `d` in `\u005b`/`\u005d` weren't in the original set. and finally calling the function with ``` `` ``` (since you can't use `\u0028\u0029` for `()`...).

I'm not sure how far off the original solution my usage of changing the number to base 36 is, but it was better than my original attempts to get the function names via `Object.keys`!

A fun challenge indeed!

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##zVLBasMwDL33K4xPCbsYx7bswf5ixxzatQoNdHZwHFi/PlstZ8Swy9hlp6cnPUlPoOmersF36/p2TzhjYi@Mcy5kp7QB6/r@iMPylTkczuGCVO37RQhllowGCboMoIg5gqFIjr9vySAtAZASKmWZovZ9D0kONGVlGWOtA60EMaSiHGrqCq1ckUZXVkH@5APKqs58j9s7UfuD/nAJgBNgjLD/5ZZtl5YVhYpt0vxJUxx9avjrFdk5vE@nOM7Bs4hpiR4vz4w/zSk2p9ut@WCjZ9tnDiGynHh8Ytu26/oJ)

Comment: Congrsts, nice work! Not exactly the same as my answer, but that's kind of to be expected since there's so many ways to solve it within this technique.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah, I didn't know what kind of approach it'd be after the initial, I'd be intrigued to see yours though, for sure! Thanks again for the challenge, I enjoyed it, and learned something!

Answer (score 1):

## [CPython 3.6.2, by wizzwizz4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread/136857#136857) (A000720)

```
t=int().__sub__(int()==int())
t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));
t=int().__sub__(t).__sub__(int()==int())
d=__builtins__.__dict__;l=list(d);
c=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
_=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
dd=d[l[_]].__dict__
ll=list(dd)
d[l[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](dd[ll[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](d[l[_]](),(d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))))))
```

Fairly trivial to crack the second challenge once I've cracked the first. Input to the obfuscator:

```
def f(n):
 r=[]
 p=[]
 for v in range(2,n):
  if v not in r:
   r.extend(v*x for x in range(n))
   p.append(v)
 return len(p)
print(f(int(input())))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), [TehPers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137125/71434)

```
$+77*6%6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9fRdvcXMtM1ez/fxMA)

Explanation:

```
$          Take input
 +77       double it
    *6     square it
      %6   print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5 by theLambGoat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136480/48198)

First time using Perl, probably there's a nicer way.. It's the standard algorithm for a base conversion that I use here.

```perl
sub f { $n = 1-1; $b = -(-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1); $ten = $b-(-1-1); if ($_[$n] == $n) { return $n; } return ($_[$n]%$b) - f(int($_[$n]/$b))/(-1/$ten); }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhTaFaQSVPwVbBUNfQWkElCcjS1dA1RIWaQJmSVJAqlSSILFAkM01BQyU@WiUvVsEWKJGnCTSpKLWktCgPyLFWqIVxoIpUVZI0FXQV0jQy80qgQvpAIU19oHn6INOBRtb@LygCSgMV2QSHuHj62Wla/7cEAA)

#### Explanation

For other bases you could just replace `$b` by that base's value..

```perl
sub f {
  $n = 1-1;                                # construct value for 0
  $b = -(-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1);                # construct the value for the base (8)
  $ten = $b-(-1-1);                        # construct value for 10

  if ($_[$n] == $n) {                      # if the argument is 0:
    return $n;                             #   we're done (base case)
  }
                                           # else:
  return ($_[$n] % $b)                     #   return current digit..
       - f(int($_[$n] / $b))               #   ..plus remaining digits..
                            /(-1/$ten);    #   ..multiplied by 10 (shift left by one position)
}
```

[Check the source!](https://tio.run/##VY/dCoIwFMfve4rTmLARQ6S7xLfoLiKcbjiwM5kTiujZ7SyViN3s/8HvnDM8Y@fxOM/6Gc1oIlTAGBsnDS9nBb9diuu@ynIZTFRYvinb7Rrfml/Pwgs4ki5UUQLX9FNCFf9PUhJNanG9pOQ4C2kCxytUFKAkEs2ZApIo4b2JtZRxLUGBFQ7jauVkyZx4eaITcllwCKnCzp2Bxt@HOrjR40oz7QnYYYxB1H0vHuAQttOtD/A10oFSynn@AA)