# "Hello, World!" (Cops' thread)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers, hello-world

*This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/137743/61563).*

Your challenge is to write a program or function that, with a certain input, prints the exact string `Hello, World!` and a newline. Capitalization, spacing and punctuation must be exact.

Input may be taken via standard input, a file, or command-line/function arguments. Output may be given via return value, writing to a file, or standard output.

Your program must print `Hello, World!` for at least one input. When your program is given the wrong input (i.e. the input that does not make it print `Hello, World!`), it can do whatever you like - crash, print random nonsense, call Chuck Norris, etc.

**You may not use a hashing algorithm or any similar methods of obscuring the required input.**

Submissions are preferred to be runnable & crackable on [TIO](//tio.run). Submissions not runnable or crackable on TIO are allowed, but please include instructions to download / run them.

After one week, this challenge will be closed to future cop submissions. The winner is the shortest code that is uncracked after a week of posting it ("it" being the code, not this challenge). The winner will be accepted after two weeks.

After a week has passed since posting, please mark your answer as safe and show the input (in a `> ! spoiler quote`). If a robber cracks your submission (before the week ends), please mark it as cracked and show the halting input (in a `> ! spoiler quote`).

## Looking for uncracked submissions?

```js
fetch("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/137742/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36vlFcdkRGfButLhYEngU&key=kAc8QIHB*IqJDUFcjEF1KA((&pagesize=100").then(x=>x.json()).then(data=>{var res = data.items.filter(i=>!i.body_markdown.toLowerCase().includes("cracked")).map(x=>{const matched = /^ ?##? ?(?:(?:(?:\[|<a href ?= ?".*?">)([^\]]+)(?:\]|<\/a>)(?:[\(\[][a-z0-9/:\.]+[\]\)])?)|([^, ]+)).*[^\d](\d+) ?\[?(?:(?:byte|block|codel)s?)(?:\](?:\(.+\))?)? ?(?:\(?(?!no[nt][ -]competing)\)?)?/gim.exec(x.body_markdown);if(!matched){return;}return {link: x.link, lang: matched[1] || matched[2], owner: x.owner}}).filter(Boolean).forEach(ans=>{var tr = document.createElement("tr");var add = (lang, link)=>{var td = document.createElement("td");var a = document.createElement("a");a.innerHTML = lang;a.href = link;td.appendChild(a);tr.appendChild(td);};add(ans.lang, ans.link);add(ans.owner.display_name, ans.owner.link);document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(tr);});});
```

```html
<html><body><h1>Uncracked Submissions</h1><table><thead><tr><th>Language</th><th>Author</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133417/codebreakers-and-codewriters) not a dupe though.

Comment: As I said in the sandbox, I feel that this is a duplicate of the [halting question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135363/31625) since any answer there could be posted here instead but with code for and infinite loop replaced with code to print hello world. I won't vote yet because I'd hammer, but I'm pretty convinced this is a dupe.

Comment: Obviously `sha3` falls into that category, but otherwise where do you draw the line? I mean the `mod 1e3` is also a hash function, and I'd even go so far and argue that many of the submissions are going to be hash functions, as this challenge is basically asking for such.

Comment: Is the trailing newline entirely necessary? I just added a byte to the end of my submission, but still I see a few other people have missed it off too.

Comment: What exactly counts as a hashing algorithm? Would summing the codepoints of a string be a hashing algorithm? How about treating a string as a base-256 number?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Related, but not dupe. In case of no comparing with "Hello world" its different. For example when doing some input manipulations.

Comment: Based on the answers I've seen in the past day, nothing has appeared that convinces me this isn't a duplicate. I'm going to close the cop challenge for now, and if the community disagrees it can be reopened, and if the community agrees they can close the robber thread too.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman now i am developing non dupe crackme. To avoid dupe submissions you can edit rules

Comment: @Dopapp this has already been discussed, here (some comments deleted) and in chat. Answers cannot be copy-pasted, nor very easily ported, from that challenge to this one, so they are not duplicates.

Comment: Can cop's program interact with crack? i.e. robber's program do calculations, based on debug output of cop's program, and then send suitable for this case input

Comment: What's a "*similar method of obscuring the required input*"? I'm doing some calculations on numerical input in one of my submissions, but nothing that's specifically hard to reverse (like a hash function is), so I guess this is ok?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I believe that mostly is directed at one-way functions (hash functions), RSA stuff (giant primes) or the like

Comment: I assume that, just wanted to be sure my C64 submission isn't against the rules :)

Comment: I think I should post [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/viable-input-forms-in-cops-and-robbers-challenges) to gather more discussion as to what kind of inputs are valid; because as it stands, some cracks are really stretching the definition of a input a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>191</s> 186 bytes (SAFE!)

Same as my previous answer, but without the noob eval statement, so that somebody actually has to solve the problem I created.

```
import sys
from numpy import *
e=enumerate
c='Hello, World!'
print(''.join([c[int(sum([c*cos(n*i)for i,c in e(fromiter(sys.argv[1:],float))])+.01)]for n in[2*i+ord(n)for i,n in e(c)]]))
```

now execute it with the correct parameters, such as `python3 hw.py 1 2 3`

---

*Edit*: previous version was missing a comma in "Hello, World!", and also I realized that it had an unnecesary ennumerate, which is now gone.

---

*Edit 2*: Just for fun, here is an almost identical Pyth version (47 bytes) of the same code:

```
KEJ"Hello, World!"jkm@J.Rs.e*b.t*dk1K0.e+*2kCbJ
```

Input is taken from `stdin` and is in the form of a list of arguments, such as `[1,2,3]`

I see no point in posting a separate answer because if you crack the Pthyon3 version, then you also crack the Pyth version, even without knowing Pyth.

---

Answer:

> python3 hw.py 10.72800138 13.23008796 19.30176276 16.13233012 18.10716041 0.98306644 8.18257475 19.20292132 10.99316856 -2.15745591 6.01351144 5.45443094 10.41260889

Explanation of code:

> `''.join()` creates the hello world string out of an array of characters from the string `"Hello, World!"`.  The puzzle is solved when those indicies are `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`.  Each index is calculated from an input and the constants given on the command line.  The inputs are a hard coded series: `[2*i+ord(c) for i,c in enumerate('Hello, World!')]`.  The funtion that relates the input, the constants, and the output (indicies) is this: `sum([c*cos(x*i) for i,c in enumerate(CONSTANTS)])`.  This is a classic modelling problem, where you are trying to fit data to your model.

Arriving at the solution, in python:

> ```
> from scipy import optimize
> x = [2*i+ord(c) for i,c in eumerate('Hello, World!')]
> y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].
> # make your function: 13 terms means we can achieve 13 exact outputs
> def f(x,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):
>     return sum([c*cos(x*i) for i,c in enumerate([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m])])
> # curve fit
> ans,_ = optimize.curve_fit(f,x,y)
> # check answer
> [round(f(a,*ans),0) for a in x] # should be 0-12
> ```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, `literal_eval()` in the `ast` module can be used to safely evaluate expressions, so that the `print(` code injection problem wouldn't work. It's probably not relevant here, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: are you sure this can print `Hello, World!`? Haven't cracked yet, but it looks like it's missing a comma (only 12 iterations in join loop)

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is missing a comma.  I will correct it now.

Comment: @Challenger5 thank you, I did not know that.

Answer (score 12):

## TeX - 38 bytes [Cracked(ish)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138130/73219)

This is worth a shot, because I can't imagine anyone on a site about writing short pieces of code would know TeX:

```
\read16to\x\message{Hello, World!}\bye
```

To run it, you should get a hold of some form of TeX that allows interactive mode. Save this to a file, and run TeX (or pdfTeX, XeTeX, etc.) on it.

Edit: I'm currently considering this semi-cracked. The intended solution uses input from stdin, but TeXnically input from the way the program is invoked is valid. I'll be adding more devious TeX answers if someone gets the intended method.

Here's the intended solution:

> ^C Ia - The first key is control-c, which causes an error. Then, you press I (capital i) to input a command. Then you type a (or anything else to be typeset). Normally, the message that was printed to stdout would be followed by a space and then a ')'. When you typeset something, it causes the font information to be output after the message. That means that a newline is thrown in, and the ')' gets moved later.

That may be underhanded, but should still be within the rules of the game.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Good first answer

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to use `tex \ Hello, world!\bye` (23 bytes)?

Comment: @Werner that would allow user input?

Comment: Is this actually meant to be cracked? :o

Comment: @agoldman: What follows `tex` *is* input. Whether that qualifies according to the question I don't know.

Comment: You can crack this if you're an evil, devious TeXacker. There will be an answer eventually.

Comment: Is using the commandline arguments of tex for "wrapping" this ok?

Comment: @FelixPalmen eh, I would consider it only fair to post an answer that interacts with the program written. You can't completely take advantage of the ability to give arbitrary input. But if you're thinking of what I'm thinking, yes that's a fair answer, but not the intended one.

Comment: Well, I won't give details here of course. Calling this from my own commandline snippet of TeX commands, I can make it print "Hello, World!" **with** the newline. But I can't so far with **only** input from `stdin`. So you say there's a way to do it? Of course I don't want to submit a "lame" crack ;)

Comment: Ok, I *suggest* [this crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138130/71420). Please judge for yourself if it is somewhat similar to what you had in mind. If fiddling with the environment is considered "wrong", I'll retract it.

Comment: `texnically` oh, gosh.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix that </joke>

Comment: @FelixPalmen I put up the intended input. I still think your crack is at least as fair as what I intended.

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 538 bytes, [Cracked by rexroni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138262/66104)

```
v
\">/v>v\v</>"
/!?lp%*2di%*2di
a
v   "        "       "
   "l"      "o"  /  "e"
v   "        "     " "
      "   /       "l"/
v    "!"           "
 //   " " "      \
v     \"d"o"   " "    "
      " " "   "o"r"  "!"
v"   "H"       " "    "
"l"   ""
""    "r" "         "
    \  " "l"       "d"  "
v   "     "      "  "  "H"
   "e"         /","     "
v " " "     "  " "
 "e" "W"  /"d""l"
v " " "     "  "      "
   "H"               "!"
v   "                 "
                        v
>>"Hello world?"       >o<
                        ^
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVDLCsIwELznK@KAFxEWPJf02j/wEgQhFQuBSIX4@TXZvKrWHJLd7Mzs7tym531ZvNBQ5JXXviMFQbvePvaHk5n4ElfhpZSQ@ZQAIl42p3AhoPCO2IIjwXNOpWZBjJbYVUKSJkqsIqQTTmoYblUqTTZ9hOIM1hOe86HOWwhpZoQgfcxo02Y9zXBbqSZKrvZC3QXcgq0YmwrhmIGB1LZANiJCcY6GBeXQ5he0cnhYO5O9@rT4a/it44VSGEZrnXy52Zq@kJXr/pIuy/IG), or you may want to use the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).

The first three lines read in a string from STDIN and use its charcodes mod 26 as coordinates to put the characters "`>/v>v\v</>`" into the maze below. The intended solution is a 20-character string made of the letters A–Z only (although you're allowed to use anything you want, of course).

Solution:

> The intended input is [`OCEANICWHITETIPSHARK`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_whitetip_shark) (it's a fish!). The path through the maze looks like:
>
> ```
> v
> \">/v>v\v</>"
> /!?lp%*2di%*2di
> a                |  |
> v   "        "   |  |"
> | v"l"______"o"__/  "e"
> v | "        "     " "
> | |   "   /       "l"/
> v |  "!"           "|
> |//   " " "    v_\  |
> v|    \"d"o"   " "  | "
> ||    " " "   "o"r" |"!"
> v"   "H"       " "  | "
> "l"___""_______ _/__/_____
> ""    "r" "    | |  "
> |>__\  " "l"   | | "d"  "
> v   "     "    | "  "  "H"
> |  "e"v________/"," |   "
> v " " "     "  " "  |
> |"e"|"W"  /"d""l"|  |
> v " " "     "  " |  | "
> <  "H">__________ __\"!"__
> v   "            |  | "
>     >____________ __ ___v
> >>"Hello world?" |  |  >o<
>                  |  |   ^
> ```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138262/63446)  Took me forever.

Comment: Hey, I suspected the answer might be a word, but I didn't make any attempt to unscramble it.  I stand even more impressed.

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, 59 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137769/31516)

This works in Octave 4.2.0. I can't guarantee compatibility with all versions.

```
i=input('');printf('%c',i*~all(isequal(i,'Hello, World!')))
```

Note: This doesn't print any trailing spaces or newlines. This is what it looks like:

[image]

It basically says: "Print the input string, unless the input is 'Hello, World!', in which case it should print nothing (or the null-character).

Comment: I'm not sure if `%c` means *string* or *char*...maybe you're hiding something? Also the `*~` makes me a bit suspicious...

Comment: I'm not sure, but [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137769/48198)?

Comment: @BruceForte prints a null byte at the end of output, I'm not sure that's valid... [link](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/0zYzr6C0RENdXdO6oCgzryRNQ101WV0nU6suMSdHI7M4tbA0EUjrqHuk5uTk6yiE5xflpCiqa2pq/v8fbW6ko2BoYAgiLGCEIZBrYqKjYAyUszCHChgamsAVGQDljHUUDGIB)

Comment: @MDXF Me neither, but it might be. Did you read the motivation in my answer?

Comment: @BruceForte I did, but I'm still not sure... guess we'll just have to wait for OP.

Comment: My submission doesn't have `\00` in there, but it's somewhat similar so I consider it cracked. I won't reveal the "trick" just yet, in case I want to use something related in another answer.

Comment: @StewieGriffin But it's not the `\n` is it? Because that caused quite some confusion in the robber thread.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intended solution is [this](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/0zYzr6C0RENdXdO6oCgzryRNQ101WV0nU6suMSdHI7M4tbA0EUjrqHuk5uTk6yiE5xflpCiqa2pq/v8frWtiZGliaWZuZGSio2BoYAgiLGCEIZBrAhQ3NtJRsDCHChgamsAVGQDljGMB) kind of thing.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, yes, that's what I was going for =) I suggest you post that as a [separate crack](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10578/31516), since it doesn't contain any unprintables and is therefore "more correct".

Comment: @BruceForte, no. there was no `\n`. I thought the question text said "_optional trailing newline_".

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137773/53748))

```
q5/:i:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9BU3yrTKvn/fwA)

Intended input:

> ```
> 65608656376564465644656476558065568656236564765650656446563665569
> ```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137773/53748)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Darn! That wasn't the intended input though.

Answer (score 5):

## [Explode](https://github.com/stestoltz/Explode), 23 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137790/53748)

```
@_?&4_-j>5&f^~c>&6\|4>7
```

More coming, this is just the beginning >:)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S60oyMlPSf3/3yHeXs0kXjfLzlQtLa4u2U7NLKbGxM78//@Q1OKS/wA)**

### Explorer Explanation

There are four explorers in this program. I'm not entirely sure that wait (`>`) is working correctly.

```
@_?
```

Read user input (`?`), write and extend the tape (`@`) down (`_`).

```
&4_-j>5
```

For 4 ticks (`4`), modify the tape (`&`) downwards (`_`), jumping by 5 (`5`), by subtracting (`-`) 19 (`j`).

```
&f^~c>
```

For 16 ticks (`f`), modify the tape (`&`) upwards (`^`) in a wave (`~`), alternating no affect, +13, no affect, and -13 (`c`).

```
&6\|4>7
```

For 6 ticks (`6`), modify the tape (`&`) in both directions (`|`), decreasing (`\`) by 4 (`4`) each time, and jumping by 7 (`7`). Decreasing means that it subtracts 4 the first time, 8 the second time, etc.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137790/53748) but feel free to give an explanation of the goings on :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan explanation added, sorry I took so long

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/hello-world-robbers-thread/137804#137804)

```
tsZp?x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6Q4qsC@4v//aEMFIwVjBRMF01gA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137804/12012), but if this isn't the intended solution, it feels a bit like cheating.

Comment: @Dennis The intended solution was `['Hello,' 1 'World!']`. Why cheating? :-( The doc/help for `D` says _Most input characters below 32 are replaced by space_

Comment: I meant cheating on my part, turning an LF newline into a CR+LF newline.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, I see. Well, I think it's perfectly valid too

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>173</s> <s>169</s> <s>163</s> <s>150</s> <s>151</s>  <s>148</s> 143 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138379/41938))

Let's have something totally different... and *totally evil*.

```
const e=eval,p=''.split,c=''.slice,v=[].every,f=s=>(t=c.call(s),typeof s=='string'&&t.length<81&&v.call(p.call(t,`\n`),l=>l.length<3)&&e(t)(t))
```

Usage: `f(something) // returns 'Hello, World!'`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwEAC/0lPSwBoQLx7cfsQKDXFbI0saukugr49iEQZmDvMONUjcUtFTXp/UWlyzaEdINTAUtNZL4aQQf8kpElS8PzxV2naYUXDoFaOPgbkXB7oXWudOEK3olvJijVHPlBd93a5nY@qxlkMK05gnB4wD/6@LM4Z6dV9cax8)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63426/discussion-between---and-voile).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138379/41938)

Comment: Nice! That's a real crack.

Comment: This was really tough to crack. Good job!

Comment: It's directly taken from one of the puzzles I've created on elsewhere :) (I'll let people figure out where I posted the original puzzle.)

Comment: Also, bonus challenge: do this without invoke `e` at all :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>130</s> 152 bytes, [CRACKED](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/hello-world-robbers-thread/137786#137786)

+22 bytes, I forgot about trailing newline... Program works the same as before, the newline is added to any output.

```cs
a=>a.Distinct().Select((x,y)=>a.Reverse().Skip(y).First()*x%255).Take(a.First()-33).Concat(new int[]{10}).Select(x=>(char)x).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNSwMxEL3vr4gHIZFtUEtPdReKUjzopRV6KD0M2akOTZOaSesupb99zdovfIdh5r35eIzhnvEB2y2T@xTThiOu9Ru572GWOVgjb8Dgic/2mUgwFpjF6C8/Mh04QiQjdp4q8Q7kpLpI16YO460zTxxDupcL8wVhvijFUhQtFCXoF@JIzkSp9BQtpkTWeaM6aYI7DIydsqKNbJQeU@DUeVffPg4GSn/ACiWc2V6/r/SzdwaidPgjyMX5Yv9wf7hsrotSdgZUnWb9KARopGqH/9ymBewt6lmgiHIpz/UEoUpvSm6Uuk4csmM8tK9orc/FzAdb3fwC)

Byte count also includes

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

For a start I went for something not too crazy. It can has multiple answers.

The "official" crack:

> . !$0%>5&8'#?)S*TuE[MRX`+9

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137786/71434)

Answer (score 4):

## tcc, 89 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137803/14306) by Dennis

```
#!/usr/bin/tcc -run
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("\n");
}
#include "/dev/stdin"
```

This is particularly evil due to tcc's dynamic resolution. Lots of functions are predeclared and trying to overwrite them simply doesn't work.

Comment: Could you create a working TIO link for people to play with? ([this](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/19ZUb@0uEg/KTNPH8hX0C0qzeNSzsxLzilNSVWwKS5JyczXy7Dj4srMK1HITczM09DkquZSAIKC0pJiDaWYPCVNa65ahBYl/ZTUMn2Qvjyl////JaflJKYX/wcA) is no doubt incomplete - maybe it needs compiler flags or something, I have no idea) TBH I don't even know how this is meant to take input...?

Comment: Tio's tcc is not going to work. It doesn't get that this *must* be used as tcc -run rather than a separate compile and link phase.

Comment: Maybe it's runnable via a shell through there then, bash is available (I know very little regarding either tcc or bash though). Otherwise I think you should give some detailed instructions to get people going (unless my personal lack of knowledge is the issue here - as I said I don't even know how your code gets any input, all I see is a `puts` and I thought that outputs.)

Comment: Almost have a crack but I'm on mobile and `mprotect` is being a butt.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137803/12012)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 62 bytes, ([cracked by ArchDelacy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137917/12012))

```
[[ ! "${1////x}" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]]&&[[ $# = 1 ]]&&bash -c "$1"
```

No alphanumerics or forward slashes. You should have fun with this one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzpaQVFBSaXaUB8IKmqVFGzrFKKjrRJz8kpzrWJjFWJj1dSAalSUFWwVDMG8JKA@Bd1koCZDpf///yvaAwA)

Comment: [cracked by ArchDelacy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137917/12012)

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 7 bytes [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138148/63446)

```
,+[.,+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fRztaT0c79v9/AA)

Good luck. (doesn't work with every BF interpreter

Comment: Does your input work with any BF interpreter, including ones with different tape lengths? Does your input work locally, and not just on TIO?

Comment: @StepHen any length of type afaik

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138148/63446)

Comment: Does your intended solution work on TIO?

Comment: @totallyhuman thanks, edited the comment so it looks pro.  I don't know how to put non-printable input on TIO.  I passed input on stdin from a C program with a single printf statement.

Comment: @totallyhuman nope. Idk if bug

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), 159 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138370/61563))

```
+53$!7@6:2/1+551$?7@6:5+52$!7@66:3/1+552$?7@6:5+3/1+4$!7@6:5/1+3$?7@6:5+1/1+54$!7@6:3/1+552$?7@6:5+1/1+552$?7@6:5+52$!7@6:1/1+551$?7@6:5+1/1+3$!7@6:1/1+1$(@6)7
```

This will be pretty easy to those who are comfortable with Cubically. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9f29RYRdHcwczKSN9Q29TUUMUexDHVNjUCC5tZGYPFjWDiIK4JRIcpkGkMEzcEKYNKoGkxROVCTbYyRLXQEGwaXMZQRcPBTNP8/38A)

Comment: Is anybody comfortable with Cubically? :P

Comment: @totallyhuman The language is actually pretty simple once you get used to it, and it's fun to use!

Comment: @totallyhuman It looks like there aren't any turning instructions, so this seems like mostly just math with multiples of 9. Very, very convoluted math.

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138370/63446)  I think I got the intended input, but it doesn't quite work, but I'm pretty sure it fails due to an interpreter bug.  See my explanation in crack post.  If I am right, then you were right that it was actually darn easy : )

Answer (score 3):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), <strike>51</strike> 53 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138427/73219))

```
00 C0                     .WORD $C000     ; load address
20 FD AE                  JSR $AEFD
20 EB B7                  JSR $B7EB
8A                        TXA
0A                        ASL A
45 14                     EOR $14
8D 21 C0                  STA $C021
45 15                     EOR $15
85 15                     STA $15
49 E5                     EOR #$E5
85 14                     STA $14
8E 18 D0                  STX $D018
A0 00                     LDY #$00
B1 14                     LDA ($14),Y
20 D2 FF                  JSR $FFD2
C8                        INY
C0 0E                     CPY #$0E
D0 F6                     BNE *-8
60                        RTS
C8 45 4C 4C 4F 2C 20 D7   .BYTE "Hello, W"
4F 52 4C 44 21 0D         .BYTE "orld!", $D
```

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"hello.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a4g67eKCkUUjSHARRWFFUnlhRSOGNCgALEUINL/yMD/0PZgyEVMTE8sINdPUkxEIQ0="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"hello.prg"%7D%7D)

**Usage**: `SYS49152,[x],[n]`, where `x` is a 16bit unsigned integer and `n` is an 8bit unsigned integer.

> Input is 52768 and 23 (SYS49152,52768,23)
>
>  The second parameter is directly written to `D018`, a control register of the VIC-II graphics chip. Using a suitable reference, you can deduce what to write there for setting lowercase mode without changing other modes and the address of the screen memory: `$17`, or decimal `23`. With that, you can follow the arithmetics in the code, so the first parameter ends up with the correct string address in `$14/$15` (little-endian). A more in-depth explanation can be found in the crack.

[image: Screenshot]

Invoked with wrong values, a *crash* is **very likely**.

For cracking, you might want to run it in a local installation of [vice](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/), so here's a BASIC loader to paste into the emulator (`RUN` it to place the program at `$C000`):

```
0fOa=49152to49202:rEb:pOa,b:nE
1dA32,253,174,32,235,183,138,10,69,20,141,33,192,69,21,133,21,73,229,133,20,142
2dA24,208,160,0,177,20,32,210,255,200,192,255,208,246,96,200,69,76,76,79,44,32
3dA215,79,82,76,68,33,13
```

**Update:** Added two bytes for the load address to make this an executable C64 `PRG` file in response to the [discussion on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13619/71420)

Comment: Are you sure you need to call the comma checking function at the beginning? I'm under the impression that b7eb does that check, too.

Comment: `b7eb` calls `aefd`, but only *after* calling `ad8a` (parse number as float (!)(wtf)(MS)) and `b7f7` (convert that float to 16bit unsigned int) -- so I have to first call `aefd` myself for consuming the first comma.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138427/73219)! Sweet sweet vengeance!

Comment: @AGoldMan finally edited my post. Again, well done! Maybe I can come up with another C64 code that's a bit harder to crack (without being unfair), not sure yet :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137944/73228))

[The previous version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137925/73228) has a massive cheese. Let's try this again...

```
f=s=>{let r='',i=0;while(i<13)r+=!s[i][0]||s[i]=='Hello, World!'[i]||s[i++];return r};Object.freeze(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcm7DsIwDEDRX0mntEpBRYzBzGyMDFWGPhzhymqQE0CC8u2hsF2dO3WPLg5Ct7SZw4g5e4hwfDMmJaB1TdDY55UYSzrs9pUYKGJLrm3csvwCQJ@QOdTqEoTHQq/2P8Y4K5juMiv52HM/4ZC2XhBfWPoq5y8)

Author solution:

> new Proxy({v:Array(13).fill(0)},{get:(o,p)=>['a','','Hello, World!'[p]][o.v[p]++]})

Usage:

> var p=new Proxy({v:Array(13).fill(0)},{get:(o,p)=>['a','','Hello, World!'[p]][o.v[p]++]})
>  console.log(f(p))

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137944/72685)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137746)

Just to get the ball rolling...

```python
#coding:rot13
cevag vachg()==h'Hello, World!'naq'Hello, World!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Xzk5PyUzL92qKL/E0JgrObUsMV2hLDE5I11D09Y2Q90jNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRPS@xEE3k/38A)

Comment: Is it generally accepted for the OP to crack submissions?

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137746/56656)

Comment: That's interesting... I hadn't realized any "normal" language supports coding in ROT13 o_o

Comment: @ETHproductions PHP also has [native support](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) for that.

Comment: @Arnauld And you're claiming PHP is a *normal* language?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Er... no. My bad. :-P

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 18 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137755))

```
IqGQ"Hello, World!
```

This is extremely easy, and anyone that knows Pyth would crack it in the blink of an eye, but still... Note that you must put the String between quotes.

**[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=IqGQ%22Hello%2C+World%21&input=%22ENTER+THE+STRING+HERE%22&debug=0)**

Comment: **If anyone cracks it, please edit in yourselves.**

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137755)

Comment: @totallyhuman Yep

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Browser only), 95 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137759/72349))

```
try{a=JSON.parse(prompt());try{a=='[object Object]'}catch(a){alert('Hello, World!')}}catch(a){}
```

Not too hard. Has multiple solutions.

Comment: cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137759/31343

Comment: @Maltysen. That was fast! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137763/41024))

```
sLÆ½$Xṙ5O½Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y53Dbob0qEQ93zjT1P7T34e6e//8B)

Intended input:

> ```
> 〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ〡㋄ⶐ✐сᑀ⟙ⶐⶐ〡ސЀᶑ
> ```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137763/68942)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Heh that was sneaky, given it lived for over half an hour. ;)

Comment: Heh that's cuz I only saw it 10 minutes before seeing it ;P

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137770/53748))

Shouldn't be too hard though:

```
•GG∍Mñ¡÷dÖéZ•2ô¹βƵ6B
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v8wNWFiMWX//@KAokdH4oiNTcOxwqHDt2TDlsOpWuKAojLDtMK5zrLGtTZC//8)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137770/53748)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20</s>  21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137805/53748))

+1 byte - "...and a trailing newline"

```
œ?“¥ĊɲṢŻ;^»œ?@€⁸ḊFmṪ⁷
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//xZM/4oCcwqXEismy4bmixbs7XsK7xZM/QOKCrOKBuOG4ikZt4bmq4oG3////MywyLDE)**

There are, in fact, infinite solutions.

Comment: I think I [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137805/49958) this. My crack works with the `⁸` which is for some reason missing from the TIO link, so I hope I didn't confuse myself.

Comment: Sorry about the TIO mistake!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 12 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137793/53748))

```
n[>n]<[8+o<]
```

[Try it online!](https://lylang.herokuapp.com/?program=n%5B%3En%5D%3C%5B8%2Bo%3C%5D)

<s>I don't expect this to last very long, but oh well.</s> It didn't last very long.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137793/53748)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.1, 44 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137872/72546))

```
s=...loadstring(#s>4+#s:gsub("%l","")or s)()
```

Note that Lua 5.1 is a different language than Lua 5.2 or Lua 5.3. "Try it online" doesn't have Lua 5.1. You can check your Lua version by running `print(_VERSION)`. (There should be a solution in any implementation that uses PUC-Rio's Lua 5.1 core.)

As a test harness, you can use something like this:

```
function test(...)s=...loadstring(#s>4+#s:gsub("%l","")or s)()end

test[[
This is my input!
It can have multiple lines!
]]
```

[Test harness on repl.it](https://repl.it/Jy9Z/0)

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 192 bytes [Cracked I guess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137810/63446)

```
from sys import *
from numpy import *
e=enumerate
c='Hello World!'
w=eval(argv[1])
x=[ord(n)+2*i for i,n in e(c)]
print(''.join([c[int(sum([c*cos(n*i)for i,c in e(w)])+.01)]for i,n in e(x)]))
```

The text it reads is the first program argument: `python3 hw.py '[1,2,3]'`

Don't be lame and try to put a `print("Hello World!")` statement as the argument... it prints an error afterwards anyways (at least on the command line), so I don't think that should count. (Edit: somebody did exactly that)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137810/48931). Lame crack, but unrestricted eval must be punished =)

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC on TIO), 84 bytes golfed ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137875/72546))

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(x){scanf("%d",&x);printf("%2$s","Hello, World!\n",(void*)x);}
```

Here's an ungolfed version that works too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("%2$s","Hello, World!\n",(void*)x);
}
```

- Golfed: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQl1aa4JCUzXy/Djis3MTNPo0Kzujg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHrULTuqAoM68ExDdSKVbSUfJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVGMyVPS0SjLz0zR0gSqrP3/HwA)
- Ungolfed: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rM69EITcxM0@jLD8zRZOrmksBCECCFdZgZnFyYl6ahpJqipKOWoWmNRdYsKAIqAIkaqRSrKSj5JGak5OvoxCeX5STohiTp6QDNkxLE6S@9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 130 bytes (safe)

```
q'p/{'s/{{"cjaei"#}%{)},{`}%S*}%']*}%'[*~]Y8#,:Y;0a\{{__a#{\{_T=}{1$E}w\;}{"T(:T; _T=co T)
:T)0e] _T=)Y=T\t _T=(Y=T\t"S/=~}?}/}:E~;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYhBC8IgGED/ytDEOQauWyjSab9gXiTFRHZoMCoKOnx8/nXLLo/3Xt7SXuuTPyTwlwQgeUvrjVBkIHCEK7JlQMZDw2UowZ3oqJyekgeIMVHwEK1BOB5m/HiNQGyvrO5@M987K5QV0xpaCmesfzfr/0YWaQqeUaKai671Cw)

This is split across two lines for clarity; the newline is not included.

This is semi-golfed, which makes it that much harder to understand.

There are an infinite number of solutions here. If anybody wants to try and find one, I wish them good luck...

### Solution:

> `aipeepceeaiaeeeaeeeccsiiiiaesnccccjccccijcjjccejccccjaajaaaijcjeeejaajaijcccccej`

Comment: How are inputs fed into the function? I tried to feed in some inputs (via arguments and input) but no output whatsoever.

Comment: @Voile Inputs are read via STDIN. And yes, most inputs won't produce any visible output.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 107 Bytes [Thanks Евгений Новиков] ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137913/71612))

```
i=r=>{for(e="",n=0;r.length>n;o=r.charCodeAt(++n),e+=String.fromCharCode(((3^o^19)<<1^15^13)<<1));return e}
```

Call on the `i` function using a string.

*The `console.log...` is for testing purposes.*

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCoMwFEV3v8I6JZhKRTqUGKG4dO/QLRD0VW1jnjxToZR@e2rB7cI5h/swi5kbGia/n6ehBRrRPeEdwmIoRgEqSYRTBzGMk8UWFCOuqs8diUnKLLjO95WTqChrekP1qpw9S1PHBaTq6mlwXXYnHOuNMsYKjTo/8bLMdX7UefFfnEsC/yIXw1dGUYNuRguZxY5tzyy5gLUY35Bsu0vWIIQf)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save 8 bytes: (1) remove `var`, (2) `()` from one arrow-function argument, (3) replace `return` to `eval("")` (4) delete `;` at the end. 110 bytes solution: https://pastebin.com/qwdm7fT7 Good luck

Comment: Finally got 50 rep, so: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137913/73228)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137936/73228))

This simple string copy function seems to be *really* resisting you to copy any strings resembling `Hello, World!`...

```
f=s=>{let r='',i=0;while(i<13)r+=s[i]=='Hello, World!'[i]||s[i++];return r};Object.freeze(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxDsIgEIDhvU@BE5DWRuOI19nN0cF0qPRQmguYAzXR@uzY2fX/kn8ankOy7O95HeKIpThI0H0Is2CQsvGwMa@bJ1R@v91priGdfQ8gD0gUG3GKTONKLm2eF6nr3jDmBwfBX3O8TGhz6xjxjcrpqrIxpEjYUrwqp/4mWpfyAw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 71 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137938/66323))

```
{[[head(_)]..[unpull(1)if[_1>1]]]|[_()|chars|unorderedCount|[_*(_-1)]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsMgEADPzSv2uApN8FpoL33GsohURSHVYuMp5u1GaI/DMFOyNd33nSg4Y1ELnmeq6VPXFZWInrR6KGZupFG0VzDl22rKxbri7DPXtA0jUV@VYD7628QE@3SJ47DB7Q60SPhBGAXIhf8SBTTwKKajnw)

Usage: `push(/* input */) | f()` (where f is a variable that holds the function above).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137938/41805)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>135</s> 119 bytes, ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137941))

```
const t='Hello, World!',g=q=>eval(`(function(p,q${q}){return eval(p),eval(q)})`),f=s=>g('')(s,0)==t&&g('=1')(s,0)!=t&&t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlLCoMwFACvEqGYPHiF9gDPdW/QrSFGsYR8n27Es8cqroaZ@elVF5PnyE8fBlurCb6wYJIf61xA8Q3ZDY3EiRJ1dtVO9WpcvOE5eBUxPba0w5YtL9mL60fAiwl26AFHKtRNSkpQBV9AxG37V3rfoTkD13oA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137941/72685)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 88 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137956/6828) by w0lf

```ruby
require'prime'
n=gets.to_i
n.prime?&&$><<n.to_s(36)[0,5].capitalize
$><<", #$'"if/30191/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFW9oCgzN1WdK882PbWkWK8kPz6TK08PLGivpqZiZ2OTBxIs1jA204w20DGN1UtOLMgsSczJrErlAkkr6Sgoq6grZabpGxsYWhrq//9vmFtZXJJaVAkA)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137956/3527)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 80 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138047/71420)

```c
#define O(c)(((char**)v)+c)
#define W(c)*(O(c)-**O(2)+x)
main(x,v){puts(W(42));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncq7DoJAEAXQnq8gsbl3cJuFzo@gpF6H1wZZjSghMf46oxbW56gbVM0ObdfH1OU1lAB0DHcRriyU2d@arwl@w4nU8Cw2ZnOICdtx5ev2fCxoUHny9Daz8zWmySq/a38Jw2JuLv0H)

Provide command line arguments for the desired output.

The intended input commandline was:

> "Hello, World!" ,

Quick explanation:

> The program does some pointer arithmetics on `argv[]`, using the first `char` of the second argument and the argument count. See the robbers' post for a full explanation. There are other solutions possible, but the one over there is the most simple one.

**Important**: This won't work when e.g. built for `amd64`, therefore the compiler switch `-m32` on tio.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138047/73229)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 23 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138090/71420))

```
eval<>;END{print$x='x'}
```

Usage: takes one line of input of stdin and evals it. The END block keeps simple attempts like `print"Hello, World!\n";exit` from working.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDHHxs7a1c@luqAoM69EpcJWvUK99v9/AA)

> our $x;package X;require Tie::Scalar;@ISA=qw(Tie::Scalar);sub TIESCALAR{my$v;return bless\$v,'X';}sub STORE{}sub FETCH{return "Hello, World!\n"}tie $x,'X';

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138090/71420)

Answer (score 1):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 94 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139094/71420))

```
00 C0 20 FD AE 20 9E AD 20 A3 B6 A0 00 B9 25 C0 C0 01 F0 21 C0 07 F0 1D C0 0B
F0 19 20 20 C0 C8 D0 EB 51 22 4C D2 FF F0 48 FA A2 1C 6D 72 30 06 A9 03 48 7C
A3 8D 48 C0 B9 26 C0 8D 45 C0 B9 27 C0 8D 46 C0 A2 00 BD FD AE 49 23 20 20 C0
C8 E8 E0 03 D0 F2 C0 0E D0 B5 49 1A 8D 18 D0 60
```

Disassembled:

```
00 C0       .WORD $C000       ; load address
20 FD AE    JSR $AEFD
20 9E AD    JSR $AD9E
20 A3 B6    JSR $B6A3
A0 00       LDY #$00
B9 25 C0    LDA $C025,Y
C0 01       CPY #$01
F0 21       BEQ $C033
C0 07       CPY #$07
F0 1D       BEQ $C033
C0 0B       CPY #$0B
F0 19       BEQ $C033
20 20 C0    JSR $C020
C8          INY
D0 EB       BNE $C00B
51 22       EOR ($22),Y
4C D2 FF    JMP $FFD2
F0 48       BEQ $C06F
FA          .BYTE $FA
A2 1C       LDX #$1C
6D 72 30    ADC $3072
06 A9       ASL $A9
03          .BYTE $03
48          PHA
7C A3       .WORD $A37C
8D 48 C0    STA $C048
B9 26 C0    LDA $C026,Y
8D 45 C0    STA $C045
B9 27 C0    LDA $C027,Y
8D 46 C0    STA $C046
A2 00       LDX #$00
BD FD AE    LDA $AEFD,X
49 23       EOR #$23
20 20 C0    JSR $C020
C8          INY
E8          INX
E0 03       CPX #$03
D0 F2       BNE $C044
C0 0E       CPY #$0E
D0 B5       BNE $C00B
49 1A       EOR #$1A
8D 18 D0    STA $D018
60          RTS
```

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"hello.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a4gnq0go7agALklwMAB8CHAB/AdwAvwGSAgwMjQ61EiTNL/8Ej6ohxtcjAGqQNIfKONSMC5JsCNRcC5J8CNRsCiAL39rkkjICDAyOjgA9DywA7QtUkajRjQYA=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"hello.prg"%7D%7D)

**Important**: When load from disk (like in this online demo), the program only works after issuing a `NEW` command! Without first doing `NEW`, you'd only ever get an `?OUT OF MEMORY ERROR` when trying to pass a string.

---

**Usage:** `SYS49152,"[string]"`, where `[string]` is your input string.

Yes, input is a **string** this time, and the white area in the screenshot below doesn't tell you anything about the required length.

[image: Screenshot]

This should be quite hard to crack, but it's possible calculating everything back, no hashes or similar involved ;) You *might* need some reference for the C64 ROMs though. Further tip: look for an area only containing *data* in the disassembly listing :)

Like with my previous entry, here's a BASIC loader to paste into [vice](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/), just `RUN` this and the program is placed at `$C000`:

```
0fOa=49152to49243:rEb:pOa,b:nE
1dA32,253,174,32,158,173,32,163,182,160,0,185,37,192,192,1,240,33,192,7,240,29
2dA192,11,240,25,32,32,192,200,208,235,81,34,76,210,255,240,72,250,162,28,109
3dA114,48,6,169,3,72,124,163,141,72,192,185,38,192,141,69,192,185,39,192,141,70
4dA192,162,0,189,253,174,73,35,32,32,192,200,232,224,3,208,242,192,14,208,181
5dA73,26,141,24,208,96
```

**Solution**:

> 8bitsareenough

**Explanation**:

> The code basically uses an XOR key of the same length as `Hello, World!\n`. As this would be quite simple to crack, the key isn't placed in the code *as is* but there are 3 times 3 bytes that are calculated from the C64's ROMs.
>
>  The 3 times 3 bytes in the data are in the format `<key>, <low>, <high>`, where `<low>, <high>` is the start address of 3 bytes in the ROM that are taken as part of our XOR key after XOR'ing them with `<key>`.
>
>  It's possible to crack it with some reference / disassembly to the C64 ROMs. Of course, it's easier to just try and get the key from the running program. I attempted to prevent the easiest method of doing this (just entering `"Hello, World!\n"`, as XOR is reversed with the same key) by forcing a crash on wrong input. The crack linked cleverly modified the program, so it won't crash.
>
>  Another nice possibility to crack this would have been to spot the single place where output happens: `EOR ($22),Y; JMP $FFD2`. If you know that fetching a string using the BASIC routines will place a pointer to that string in `$22/$23`, all you have to do is set a breakpoint at `EOR ($22),Y` and get the XOR key delivered in the accumulator byte by byte.

Comment: And [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139094/73219) again. This is good fun!

Comment: So, unfortunately, I have to give up on this. I could come up with an even harder-to-crack one but 1.) this would increase byte count and 2.) it's too late anyways. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 94 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/hello-world-robbers-thread/137946#137946)

```php
<?=constant(explode(',',$argv[1])[0]."::".explode(',',$argv[1])[1])==262144?"Hello, world
":a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OT@vuCQxr0QjtaIgJz8lVUNdR11HJbEovSzaMFYz2iBWT8nKSkkPuywQ29oamRkZmpjYK3mk5uTk6yiU5xflpHApWSVa////HwA)
First codegolf submission, feel free to help me improve this

Cracked, intended input :

> ReflectionFunction,IS_DEPRECATED

Because

> ReflectionFunction::IS_DEPRECATED = 262144

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137743/hello-world-robbers-thread/137946#137946).